# HTML forms - input type submit problem with action=URL when URL contains index.aspx

Tags: html, forms, url, parameters, action

I have a HTML form that truncates the action parameter after the "?" mark - which is NOT the desired behavior I am looking for.

Here is a representative HTML snippet:

```
<form action="http://spufalcons.com/index.aspx?tab=gymnastics&path=gym">
    <input type="submit" value="SPU Gymnastics"/>
</form>
```

In this case, the submit button takes you to the "http://www.spufalcons.com/index.aspx" page, effectively ignoring "?tab=gymnastics&path=gym" parameter.  It appears that all HTML and PHP pages referenced in the action=URL work as expected.  This behavior is consistent across all major browsers (IE, FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera).

Has anyone seen this problem before?  Or can suggest an alternative and/or workaround consistent with my "pure" CSS/HTML/PHP web development approach?  I have tried replacing the special characters with HTML entity values with no impact.  I REALLY don't want to use abandon my CSS-styled submit buttons by using Javascript or button PNG's or image maps.

Environment:

- Web Server: Apache 2.2.14
- PHP: 5.2.10
- OS: Mac OS X 10.5.8
- HTML document info:
- `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"`
  `"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
  `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

TIA --
Trent

Comment: Sounds weird. Are you sure the form actually POSTs to the wrong URL, or is it possible that the POST is correct, but the .ASPX page does a redirect?

Comment: If you are using apache and need workaround, [there are one in another stackoverflow answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear/#16415773

Answer (score 32):

Put the query arguments in hidden input fields:

```
<form action="http://spufalcons.com/index.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="tab" value="gymnastics" />
    <input type="hidden" name="path" value="gym" />
    <input type="submit" value="SPU Gymnastics"/>
</form>
```

Comment: If you want the "tab=gymnastics&path=gym" to show up in the urlbar, add method="GET" to your form tag as well.

Comment: @Annie: The `method` attribute is not required; `method="get"` is implied.

Comment: if your "Directory Index" is index.aspx(on apache config) : Can post without url.

<form action="post">blah blah</form>

Answer (score 10):

Use method=POST then it will pass key&value.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be my "preferred" solution:

```
<form action="www.spufalcons.com/index.aspx?tab=gymnastics&path=gym" method="post">  <div>
<input type="submit" value="Gymnastics"></div>
```

Sorry for the presentation format - I'm still trying to learn how to use this forum....

I do have a follow-up question. In looking at my MySQL database of URL's it appears that ~30% of the URL's will need to use this post/div wrapper approach. This leaves ~70% that cannot accept the "post" attribute. For example:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Google"/>
  </div></form>
```

does not work. Do you have a recommendation for how to best handle this get/post condition test. Off the top of my head I'm guessing that using PHP to evaluate the existence of the "?" character in the URL may be my best approach, although I'm not sure how to structure the HTML form to accomplish this.

Thank YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I applied CSS styling to an anchored HREF attribute fully emulating the push button behaviors I needed (hover, active, background-color, etc., etc.).  HTML markup is much simpler a-n-d eliminates the get/post complexity associated with using a form-based approach.

```
<a class="GYM" href="http://www.spufalcons.com/index.aspx?tab=gymnastics&path=gym">Gymnastics</a>
```