# Html form usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm trying to add a search form to my webpage:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckCourses", "Home", new { programId = ViewBag.ProgramId }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p class="col-md-12">
        Find by course or teacher name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search Course" class="btn-primary" />
    </p>
}
```

Now `CheckCourses()` is supposed to have a `programId` to run (not nullable). That's why I added `new { programId = ViewBag.ProgramId }` to the `routeHelper`. `ViewBag.ProgramId` is not null at the time this code runs, however, when I click on the `Search Course` button, I get the message that `programId`'s value is null:`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'programId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CheckCourses(Int32, System.String, System.Nullable 1[System.Int32])' in 'TanulmanyiRendszer.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters`

Full stack trace:

```
[ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'programId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CheckCourses(Int32, System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' in 'TanulmanyiRendszer.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters]
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo) +527
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765045
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

**UPDATE**

Controller as requested:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index", _programService.Programs.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult CheckCourses(int programId, string searchString, int? page) {
        var courses = from s in _courseService.Courses select s;
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        ViewBag.ProgramId = programId;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            searchString = searchString.ToLower();
            courses = courses.Where(s => s.CrsName.ToLower().Contains(searchString) || s.EducationUser.FullName.ToLower().Contains(searchString));
        }
        courses = courses.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        return View("Courses",courses.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The rendered `<form>` element shows the function worked well, however the issue still persist when pushing the search button:

```
<form action="/Home/CheckCourses?programId=2" method="get">            
    <p class="col-md-12">
        Find by course or teacher name: <input id="SearchString" name="SearchString" type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search Course" class="btn-primary">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also paste in the HTTPGet Controller Method for this view?

Comment: @MichaelBurns I added the `CheckCourses` action controller

Comment: try casting the programId explicitely to an int like `new { programId = (int)ViewBag.ProgramId }`.

Comment: Can you past the rendered HTML for the form element? You may also want to try and add an `html.hiddenfor<>` for programID as wll

Comment: @lte__What Controller Method is used to render the form view and add the original ViewBag.ProgramId? Are you using the same method CheckCourses to both render the search form and send back the search string?

Comment: @MadMyche Apparenlty the `<form>` is rendered well (see update 2).

Comment: @MichaelBurns The `Courses.cshtml` view is called from another view via `@Html.ActionLink("Check courses", "CheckCourses", "Home", new { programId = Model[i].Id, currentFilter = "", searchString = "", page = 1}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })` and the form is in this `Courses.cshtml`

Comment: If I manually enter `http://localhost:56272/Home/CheckCourses?programId=2&SearchString=dat` it works fine, but if I press that `Search course` button, it calls `http://localhost:56272/Home/CheckCourses?SearchString=dat` even though the form clearnly contains `programID` too... I don't get this :D

Comment: @lte__Everything looks correct from all I can see. Can you place a breakpoint at your CheckCourses method and see what's getting sent to that method?

Comment: @MichaelBurns I did, but funny thing is, `CheckCourses()` doesn't get called...

Comment: It's def getting called, the error even return for that method CheckCourses.

Comment: I've put a breakpoint in front of `public ActionResult CheckCourses(int programId, string searchString, int? page)` but nothing. Jumps right to the stack trace, not breaking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the programId param into a hidden field:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckCourses", "Home", FormMethod.Get)){
    <p class="col-md-12">
        @Html.Hidden("programId", ViewBag.ProgramId)
        Find by course or teacher name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search Course" class="btn-primary" />        
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that did it (with `int` instead of `string`). Can you explain why?

Comment: It appeared when you hit search it was overwriting your existing programId param when you were declaring it in the BeginForm helper method.

Comment: When you use FormMethod.Get, any param values are overwritten by the form data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548795/html-form-why-action-cant-have-get-value-in-it

Comment: I guess my comment 1/2 hour before this answer was correct: add an `html.hiddenfor<>` for programID

Comment: The `(int)` shouldn't be needed as all data in a querystring is of type nullable `string`, hence the name.