# Change onclick action with a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a button:

```
<button id="a" onclick="Foo()">Button A</button>
```

When I click this button the first time, I want it to execute Foo (which it does correctly):

```javascript
function Foo() {
  document.getElementById("a").onclick = Bar();
}
```

What I want to happen when I click the button the first time is to change the onclick function from `Foo()` to `Bar()`. Thus far, I've only been able to achieve an infinite loop or no change at all. `Bar()` would look something like this:

```javascript
function Bar() {
  document.getElementById("a").onclick = Foo();
}
```

Thus, clicking this button is just alternating which function gets called. How can I get this to work? Alternatively, what's a better way to show/hide the full text of a post? It originally starts shorted, and I provide a button to "see the full text." But when I click that button I want users to be able to click the button again to have the long version of the text go away.

Here's the full code, if it helps:

```javascript
function ShowError(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).className = document.getElementById(id).className.replace(/\bheight_limited\b/, '');
    document.getElementById(id+"Text").className = document.getElementById(id+"Text").className.replace(/\bheight_limited\b/, '');
    document.getElementById(id+"Button").innerHTML = "HIDE FULL ERROR";
    document.getElementById(id+"Button").onclick = HideError(id);
}

function HideError(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).className += " height_limited";
    document.getElementById(id+"Text").className += " height_limited";
    document.getElementById(id+"Button").innerHTML = "SHOW FULL ERROR";
    document.getElementById(id+"Button").onclick = "ShowError(id)";
}
```

Comment: I'm not making this an answer since you are specifically asking about vanilla JavaScript, but you may want to look into jQuery. It's a JavaScript library that can help you do what you are looking to do in your question.

Comment: Know about JQuery, can only use Javascript in this case. Thanks.

Comment: The `onclick` property should be in all lowercase. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick

Comment: Aren't event handlers added by using += ? And perhaps you might even need to do this: `myobject.onclick += function() { Foo(); }`

Comment: Turns out I didn't need the +=. I think += wouldn't remove the existing onclick function, right?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Your code is calling the function and assigning the return value to onClick, also it should be 'onclick'. This is how it should look.

```
document.getElementById("a").onclick = Bar;
```

Looking at your other code you probably want to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById(id+"Button").onclick = function() { HideError(id); }
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that Ryan does not include the parentheses after Bar because it is not a function call.

Comment: ... you probably want to do something like this: 

    .onclick = HideError; // if this won't work, why not. What's the diff from above answer?

Comment: @pashute The difference is that `.onclick = HideError` is going to invoke `HideError(event: MouseEvent)` whereas the above answer invokes `HideError(id)`. If you don't care about parameters, then you can do the shorter version and ignore the event that gets passes in.

Answer (score 86):

```
var Foo = function(){
    document.getElementById( "a" ).setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: Boo();" );
}

var Boo = function(){
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way to do it. Though others work, adding a function directly to onclick may not work in some scenarios. I faced an issue in a case where creating multiple buttons in a loop and assigning a function for onclick for each button in the loop was not working. It would assign the function for the last button to all the buttons. Using this method works like a charm. Thanks Hor!

Comment: Should be `onclick`, not `onClick`.

Comment: @user66001 it doesn't matter, HTML is not case sensitive

Comment: @Calne - camel case'ng it might make people think it needs to be.

Comment: Is this still true? 'onClick' did not work for me, but 'onclick' did.Using Chrome   47 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 26):

Do not invoke the method when assigning the new `onclick` handler.

Simply remove the parenthesis:

```
document.getElementById("a").onclick = Foo;
```

UPDATE (due to [new information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303899/5303931#comment5981502_5303931)):

```
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function () { Foo(param); };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i have a parameter that needs to be there. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @hatorade: use onclick = function () { Foo(params); };

Comment: @hatorade - Yes `document.getElement... function() { Foo(param);};`

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I'd give you the answer if I could, but Ryan got it a few mins sooner. Sorry :(. I did +1 though!

Comment: should that be .onclick not .onClick?

Comment: @GlennG Personally, I've never seen a difference, but documentation says lowercase onclick

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Simple and elegant

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to João Paulo Oliveira, this was my solution which includes a variable (which was my goal).

```
document.getElementById( "myID" ).setAttribute( "onClick", "myFunction("+VALUE+");" );
```

Answer (score 11):

I recommend this approach:

Instead of having two click handlers, have only one function with a if-else statement. Let the state of the BUTTON element determine which branch of the if-else statement gets executed:

HTML:

```
<button id="a" onclick="toggleError(this)">Button A</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleError(button) { 
    if ( button.className === 'visible' ) {
        // HIDE ERROR
        button.className = '';
    } else {
        // SHOW ERROR
        button.className = 'visible';
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/hPQP9/

Comment: I personally like this solution because it keeps the code for the button together (and being a toggle, if you update one side, usually you want to update the other side), but I was also working with Vue and using v-on:click, so the top answer didn't seem to be working for me.
Thanks Sime!

Answer (score 6):

You could try changing the button attribute like this:

```
element.setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: Boo();" );
```

Answer (score 4):

What might be easier, is to have two buttons and show/hide them in your functions. (ie. `display:none|block;`) Each button could then have it's own onclick with whatever code you need.

So, at first `button1` would be `display:block` and `button2` would be `display:none`. Then when you click `button1` it would switch `button2` to be `display:block` and `button1` to be `display:none`.

Comment: Perfect answer! For someone not really familiar with javascript, this is a very helpful method.

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone, like me, trying to set a query string on the action and wondering why it's not working-**

You cannot set a query string for a GET form submission, but I have found you can for a POST.

For a GET submission you must set the values in hidden inputs e.g.

an action of: `"/handleformsubmission?foo=bar"` 
would have be added as the hidden field like: `<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />`

This can be done add dynamically in JavaScript as (where clickedButton is the submitted button that was clicked:

```
var form = clickedButton.form;
var hidden = document.createElement("input");
hidden.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hidden.setAttribute("name", "foo");
hidden.setAttribute("value", "bar");
form.appendChild(hidden);
```

See this question for more info
[submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear)