# Change onClick attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

This is my function and it should change the onClick attribute of the HTML input, but if I use

```
document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = "writeLED(1,1)";
```

it does not work at all, but if I use

```
document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = writeLED(1,1);
```

the function executes by itself!
Any ideas what code do I have to use to change the onCLick attribute WITHOUT executing the function, before the button is clicked?
Here is the full function, if it matters:

```
function showLED(id){
    if(color == 0){
        document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = "writeLED(1,1)";
        document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).value="light is on";
        //document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).disabled = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = "writeLED(1,0)";
        document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).value="light is off";
        //document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = "writeLED(1,1)";` is setting the `onclick` property of the element to a string.

Comment: `document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = writeLED(1,1);` is setting the `onclick` property of the element to the result of `writeLED(1,1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change onclick action with a Javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303899/change-onclick-action-with-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Well, just do this and your problem is solved :

```
document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).setAttribute('onclick','writeLED(1,1)')
```

Have a nice day XD

Comment: thnx a lot. that is exactly the behavior I wanted.

Comment: This seems like the answer to the actual question, rather than just a kludge to get something working.

Comment: You just solved my problem after searching for a solution for hours! :) Thank you!!!

Comment: As of today, "The addEventListener() method is the *recommended* way to register an event listener" – [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). So, should it be `document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).addEventListener('onclick', writeLED.bind([1,1]))`   ? ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#getting_data_into_and_out_of_an_event_listener))

Answer (score 52):

You want to do this - set a function that will be executed to respond to the onclick event:

```
document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = function(){ writeLED(1,1); } ;
```

The things you are doing don't work because:

1. The onclick event handler expects to have a function, here you are assigning a string

   ```
   document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = "writeLED(1,1)";
   ```
2. In this, you are assigning as the onclick event handler the result of executing the writeLED(1,1) function:

   ```
   document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = writeLED(1,1);
   ```

Comment: +1 "when you have a problem - add another layer of abstraction" - classic :)

Comment: Oh I hate that. If you inspect the buttonLED element, you'll see that the onclick attribute is not being set, it's creating an ephemeral event handler that you won't be able to see in the source.

Marcelo Teixeira Ruggeri's answer below actually SETS the onclick attribute, which is what the original question asked. I won't downvote this answer because it works and was accepted, but to me, it sure does stink.

Answer (score 3):

The line  `onclick = writeLED(1,1)` means that you want to *immediately* execute the function writeLED(arg1, arg2) with arguments 1, 1 and assign the return value; you need to instead create a function that will execute with those arguments and assign that. The topmost answer gave one example - another is to use the bind() function like so:

```
    var writeLEDWithSpecifiedArguments = writeLED.bind(this, 1,1);
    document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = writeLEDWithSpecifiedArguments;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery instead of Javascript,
use `'attr'` property instead of `'setAttribute'`

like

```
$('buttonLED'+id).attr('onclick','writeLED(1,1)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually changing the function.

`onClick` is assigned to a function (Which is a reference to something, a function pointer in this case). The values passed to it don't matter and **cannot** be utilised in any manner.

Another problem is your variable `color` seems out of nowhere.

Ideally, inside the function you should put this logic and let it figure out what to write. (on/off etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set the 'onclick' attribute to a function that returns your writeLED function.

```
document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = function(){ return writeLED(1,1)};
```

This can also be useful for other cases when you create an element in JavaScript while it has not yet been drawn in the browser.

Comment: This doesn't work if element is not yet drawn.
To make it works if elements is not yet drawn, you need wo add another level of abstraction and use "addEventListener": 
document.addEventListener('click', document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id), function(){ return writeLED(1,1)});

Answer (score -1):

First we'll select the required button using query selector and for all  the selected buttons we'll set the  `onclick` attribute with a function that needs to be called by clicking on the buttons.
You can write the code for required work you want to do by clicking the button in the function defined.

Well "One of the" generalized solution to your to your problem can be achieved by the following code:

```
var a=document.querySelectorAll('button');


for(b=0;b<a.length;b++)
   {   
        a[b].setAttribute("onclick","check("+b+")");
   }
  function check(e)
   {    
    var sa=a[e].innerHTML;
    console.log('working onclick',sa);
   }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explanation, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explanation of your possible solution.