# Reloading the page only once on a button click

Tags: javascript

I have a Load button and I am calling onclick event on that button which would refresh the page using `window.location.reload()` . But ,what I want is that the reload should only be called when the button is clicked for the first time . From the second click and till the HTML page is active the reload should not be called .

How can this be achieved with javascript ?Any examples would be helpful.

Comment: Using `local/sessionStorage`

Comment: Using cookies maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**local storage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [**session storage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to do that. This is a modern approach that makes use of [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

In this case, you may set a property in the storage to hold the button click and only do the refresh if it is not yet clicked.

It is possible to do it like the following snippet:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    // will return null at the first call
    var buttonClicked = sessionStorage.getItem('isButtonClicked');

    // will only enter if the value is null (what is the case in the first call)
    if (!buttonClicked) {
        // set value to prevent further reloads
        sessionStorage.setItem('isButtonClicked', true);

        // reload the page
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

A more detailed example on the web storage API can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API), if you want to know more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be changing the action that onClick performs. Try taking a look here: [Change onclick action with a Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303899/change-onclick-action-with-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending a parameter on the first reload and using that parameter change the action of the button.

Something like:

```
<script>
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  return false;
}
var secondReload= getQueryVariable("secondReload");
if(!secondReload){
 //if button clicked
 window.location.reload();
}else{
//deactivate button
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to add a disabled attribute on the button tag within the click event.

[Reloading the page only once on a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084025/reloading-the-page-only-once-on-a-button-click)

if you're using jQuery, something like this.

```html
$('button').on('click',function()({
... your code here
$(this).attr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: It is possible to do that without disabling the button.

Comment: i read the OP as he wanted to avoid people double clicking the button while the reloaded happen. So diasable it. Or remove it from DOM.

Comment: He explicitly mentioned that "from the second click and till the HTML page is active the reload should not be called" -- so the button can still be clicked, but nothing should happen.