# DELETE link does nothing in PHP when removing data from PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have created a table in PHPMyAdmin, and I have connected to it via a localhost. My PHP code displays the data in a table.

I want to be able to delete a certain row, so I created a html/php link to delete the row within a table.

My problem is that whenever I press delete, the page just refreshes without an error but the record is still there.

Is there something missing within my code?

```
<?php
    // Connect to the database
    $username="root";$password="test";$database="products";

    // Connect to the MySQL server and select the required database
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost",$username,$password, $database);

    $sql = "";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

    $ID = isset($row['ID']) ? $row['ID'] : '';{
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM products WHERE ID=$ID");
    }

    $result = $connection->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>\n";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>\n";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>\n";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Cost_Price'] . "</td>\n";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Stock'] . "</td>\n";
            echo "<td>" . $row['EAN'] . "</td>\n";
            ?>
            <td><a href="?mode=delete&ID=<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>"
               title="Delete <?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>">Delete</a></td>
            <?php

            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
    }

$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

$connection->close();

?>
```

Comment: Could you eventually correct your code?
This is not understandable: 
`$ID = isset($row['ID']) ? $row['ID'] : '';{
                $query = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM products WHERE ID=$ID");
                }`

why is the $query part inside curly braces ?

Comment: Not related to your problem. But you should not use `GET` requests (regular links) to trigger actions that modify/delete data. Beecause browsers might prefecht links.

Comment: put your full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change**

```
$ID = isset($row['ID']) ? $row['ID'] : '';{
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM products WHERE ID=$ID");
}
```

**To**

```
if(isset($_GET['ID']) && ($_GET['mode'] == 'delete')) {
  $ID = $_GET['ID'];
  $query = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM products WHERE ID=$ID");
}
```

***Explanations***

When after clicking delete link, it comes to this line

`$ID = isset($row['ID']) ? $row['ID'] : '';{`.

Here, `$row['ID']` is not set. So,  `$ID` set to `""` as you declared in your code. So, DELETE statement is not able to find that product which you wanted to delete.

Actually, in delete link. You are passing 2 variables. One is `mode` and other is `ID` of product. Catch those 2 variables through **$_GET** as I mentioned in my answer.

***Quick Links***

1. [How to set $_GET variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415224/how-to-set-get-variable)
2. [$_GET : PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: If this answer helped you @NicholasNicolaou. Then, Please mark this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily.