# how would I go about echoing a message at the bottom of my signup page?

Tags: php

I was just wondering how I would go about getting a message to echo at the bottom of my signup page to let the user know that their email is in use.

```
$sql_email = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
    $result_email = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_email);
    $emailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result_email);

if ($emailcheck > 0) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=email");
        echo("an account with that email is already created, please enter a different email.</a>");
        exit();
    }
```

this code sends the user to signup.php?error=email where they can sign up again but I would like a message to echo below the sign-up form saying: "an account with that email is already created, please enter a different email." I tried using echo to do this but nothing appears on the page.

Comment: Well of course nothing appeared. You're sending a `Location` header that will cause the user's browser to redirect immediately to another page. Nobody is going to see the body text of your redirect page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `echo` & `exit` after `header location`. Because, it will go to sign up page with `error` as URL parameter. Then, catch it through **$_GET** and display the error message wherever you want in **sign up** page.

```
if ($emailcheck > 0) {
  header("Location: ../signup.php?error=email");
}
```

**signup.php**

(Put this code anywhere you want in sign up page.)

```
if(isset($_GET['error']) && ($_GET['error'] == 'email')){
  echo "<p>an account with that email is already created, please enter a different email</p>";
}
```

***Quick Links***

1. [How to set $_GET variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415224/how-to-set-get-variable)
2. [$_GET : PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: *Keep Coding* @kitsibu. Happy To Help.