# PHP how to add variable in href and pass to another page

Tags: php, html

I am new in PHP , I think its a silly question but I am stuck in it , How to declare php variable in link.
I am trying it but no luck Please give me a direction.

```
<li id="likastyle" style="padding-left:14%";>
    <?php echo "<a href=\"functions/mainpage.php?link=".$tmp[$i]>"";?> 
    <?php echo "$tmp[$i]"</a>;?> 
</li>
```

Comment: "<a href='functions/mainpage.php?link=".$tmp[$i].">'"

Comment: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: @PyaraLarka : I will suggest you to choose appropriate answer given below. As, it will help other user to find this answer easily. If you don't know how to mark answer as correct answer. Please have a look. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="likastyle" style="padding-left:14%";>
    <?php echo "<a href=\"functions/mainpage.php?link=".$tmp[$i]."\">".$tmp[$i]."</a>"; ?>
</li>
```

OR

```
<li id="likastyle" style="padding-left:14%";>
   <a href="functions/mainpage.php?link=<?php echo $tmp[$i] ?>"><?php echo $tmp[$i]; ?></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for early response, But what about "My link" variable??

Comment: we should always do urlencode and get parameters 
   <a href="functions/mainpage.php?link=<?php echo urlencode($tmp[$i]); ?>"><?php echo $tmp[$i]; ?></a>

Comment: Thanks Alot Fky, Its works like a charm, Thanks alot, But how can I retrieve this variable in mainpage.php,

Comment: with $_GET['link']

Comment: Fky Sorry for disturbance, I am stuck again please help, How can I pass two variables instead of one, means <a href="functions/mainpage.php?link=<?php echo $tmp[$i]&link2=$tmp2[$i] ?>"><?php echo $tmp[$i]; ?></a> , but its not working..

Comment: <a href="functions/mainpage.php?link=<?php echo $tmp[$i].'&link2='.$tmp2[$i] ?>"><?php echo $tmp[$i]; ?></a>

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate your code:

```
<li id="likastyle" style="padding-left:14%">
    <a href="functions/mainpage.php?link=<?php echo $tmp[$i]?>"><?php echo $tmp[$i]?></a>
</li>
```

With short echo syntax (`<?=`):

```
<li id="likastyle" style="padding-left:14%">
    <a href="functions/mainpage.php?link=<?=$tmp[$i]?>"><?=$tmp[$i]?></a>
</li>
```

Comment: also recommend moving all styles to external css

Answer (score 0):

In html Page

```
<li id="likastyle" style="padding-left:14%";><a href="functions/mainpage.php?link="<?php echo $tmp[$i]> ?>" ><?php echo $tmp[$i] ?></a></li>
```

In mainpage.php Page (To retrieve the variable )

```
<?php $link = $_GET['link'] ;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changes.**

**1)** Remove one extra semi colon `;` in style of `<li>`.

**2)** Change `<?php echo "$tmp[$i]"</a>;?>` to `<?php echo $tmp[$i]."</a>";?>`

**Updated Code**

```
<li id="likastyle" style="padding-left:14%">
  <?php echo "<a href=\"functions/mainpage.php?link=".$tmp[$i]>"";?> 
  <?php echo $tmp[$i]."</a>";?> 
</li>
```

I would rather suggest you not to complicate your code. And, make it simple.

```
<li id="likastyle" style="padding-left:14%">
  <a href='functions/mainpage.php?link=<?php echo $tmp[$i];?>'>
    <?php echo $tmp[$i];?>
  </a>
</li>
```

And, retrieve it in **mainpage.php** through `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

**mainpage.php**

```
<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>
```

***Quick Links***

1. [How to set $_GET variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415224/how-to-set-get-variable)
2. [$_GET : PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)