# Php global $_GET variable

Tags: php

I have two files. one is header.php and index.php. I didn't understand how `$_GET['a']` data is passing from `header.php` file to `index.php` for the routing system.

I have tried finding `$_GET['a']` passing method from header.php to index.php

**Image is a portion of the `header.php` file**
[image]

```
  /*index.php*/

include("sources/header.php");
$a = protect($_GET['a']);
switch ($a) {
    case "account": include("sources/account.php"); break;
    case "login": include("sources/login.php"); break;
    case "register": include("sources/register.php"); break;
    case "track": include("sources/track.php"); break;
    case "testimonials": include("sources/testimonials.php"); break;
    case "affiliate": include("sources/affiliate.php"); break;
    case "contact": include("sources/contact.php"); break;
    case "about": include("sources/about.php"); break;
    case "faq": include("sources/faq.php"); break;
    case "page": include("sources/page.php"); break;
    case "exchange": include("sources/exchange.php"); break;
    case "search": include("sources/search.php"); break;
    case "password": include("sources/password.php"); break;
    case "email-verify": include("sources/email-verify.php"); break;
    case "logout":
        unset($_SESSION['bit_uid']);
        unset($_COOKIE['bitexchanger_uid']);
        setcookie("bitexchanger_uid", "", time() - (86400 * 30), '/'); //         86400 = 1 day
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: $settings[url]");
        break;
    default: include("sources/homepage.php");
}
```

I expect to know how $_GET['a'] is passing from header.php to index.php

Comment: Nothing gets passed from `header.php` to `index.php`. `$_GET` (like $_SESSION and $COOKIE) are globally available.

Comment: `$_GET` is a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). Which means it is available in all scopes throughout a script.

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you are combining some base URL (`$settings[url]`) with a link keyword, `testimonials`, `affiliate`, etc. So there is probably some URL rewriting involved (.htaccess), that rewrites those incoming requests from `/foo` to `somescript.php?a=foo`

Comment: Then what is the value of $_GET['a'] ??? and where this value is inserted into $_GET['a']?? @kerbholz

Comment: `$_GET['a']` is a URL parameter. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php. Set in your URL or maybe somewhere in that `protect()` function. Or, as @misorude stated, in a server rewrite

Comment: @misorude you got the point.Kindly tell me what is the location htaccess file?? this url rewriting method works only in live server not loclhost???

Comment: URL rewriting in Apache can be configured in multiple places, but most likely you are looking for an .htaccess file at the domain root level of the project.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET` query contains the `keys/values` array that are passed to your script in the URL.

If you have the following URL:

`http://www.example.com/test.php?a=login`
Then `$_GET` will contain :

array
  'a' => string 'login' (length=5)

`$_GET` is not read-only, you could also set some values from your PHP code, if needed :

You can pass data to `$_GET` in your `header.php`
`$_GET['a'] = 'register';`
But this doesn't seem like good practice, as `$_GET` is supposed to contain data from the URL requested by the client.

In header.php file you need change urls
`<a href="<?= $_GET['a'] ?>">Link</a>`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5415248/8323534)