# How to describe URL in Django - still need an answer

Tags: python, django, forms, url, get

I'm trying to make a simple search and return results in a paginated form. Whenever I try to go to the second page, my search term is lost and thus my second page has no results.

I've found and followed the [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/pagination/) example in the Djangoproject tutorial, but I haven't found an example on how to write my URL for the search view.

I've used `POST` method in my form previously, for when I had little data to display (although now, after a bit of research, I know the usage difference between `GET` and `POST`). When I gained lots more data, I was constrained to use Pagination. Thus, I've changed my form method to `GET` but here is my problem, I don't know how to describe my `URL` so the data is sent to the right view.

I've tried to make it work with `POST` but with no success. Finally I decided to stick to `GET` example but stumbled on this URL thing that's keeping me back.

Here is the code in the template and the URLs file:

**search.py:**

```
<form method="GET" id="searchForm" action="/search/?page=1">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="billSearched" name="q_word">
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Look for" %}">
</form>
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$','ps.views.bills',name="bills"),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^search/$','ps.views.search',name="search"),)
```

I've tried many forms for the `URL` but none have succeeded.

i.e.:

`url(r'^search/(?P<page>\d+)/$','ps.views.search',name="search")`
`url(r'^search/','ps.views.search',name="search")`
`url(r'^search/(?P<page>\d+)/(?P<searchTerm>\w*)','ps.views.search',name="search")`

Any explanation / solution would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

```
def search(request):
    searchTerm = ""
    page = 1
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    if 'q_word' in request:
        searchTerm = request.GET['q_word']
    if 'page' in request:
        page = request.GET['page']
    found_bills = Bill.objects.filter(name__icontains = searchTerm)
    paginator = Paginator(found_bills,25)
    try:
        current_page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        current_page = paginator.page(1)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        current_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    bills_list = list(current_page.object_list)
    return render_to_response('results.html',{"bills_list":bills_list,"current_page":current_page,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**UPDATE #2:**

If I use `pdb` I can see that there is no data being passed from the client to the server. Got to work on that, but still, any information and/or hints would be really appreciated as they can shorten my search time :)

`(Pdb) request.GET`

`<QueryDict: {u'page': [u'1']}>`

Comment: You can remove "{% csrf_token %}" now. It is used only on POST requests.

Comment: Relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1116026/781695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form's method is `GET`, you cannot append a query string to the action, because the browser will overwrite it. You can only do that if your form method is `POST`.

Change your form to this:

```
<form method="GET" id="searchForm" action="/search/">
    <input type="text" id="billSearched" name="q_word">
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Look for" %}">
</form>
```

In your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def search(request):
    if 'q_word' in request:
        searchTerm = request.GET['q_word']

    found_bills = Bill.objects.filter(name__icontains = searchTerm)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(found_bills,25)
    try:
        current_page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        current_page = paginator.page(1)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        current_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    # bills_list = list(current_page.object_list) - not needed
    return render(request,
                  'results.html',{"results":current_page,"term": searchTerm})
```

In `results.html`:

```
{% for bill in results %}
     # .. display bill stuff
{% endfor %}

{% if results.has_previous %}
     <a href="{% url search %}?page={{ results.previous_page_number }}&q_word={{ term }}">previous</a>
{% endif %}

{% if results.has_next %}
      <a href="{% url search %}?page={{ result.next_page_number }}&q_word={{ term }}">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but it doesn't work. It says that `local variable 'searchTerm' referenced before assignment`. And if I add a simple else statement and declare the variable `searchTerm` then I get a error for the `page` value as well saying that it is `NoneType`. I'm guessing the variables are not sent in the HTTP request, but why? The code seems ok..

Comment: I've used `pdb` to see what the HTTP request looks like and the GET dictionary is empty. I have no idea where the variables go to..

Comment: It is saying that because your logic does not account for when the person submits an empty form - I only updated the parts of your code that has to do with pagination.

Comment: But why isn't the data being sent in the GET request? I understand where the logic in my view "fails", but that's because there is no data being sent.. any ideas why?

Comment: I have just finised another post with a question regarding this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412937/no-data-is-sent-with-get-method

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'describe' your url?  Your urls.py look fine.  Did you drop a debugger into your `ps.views.search()` function to verify that it is hitting?  Did you look at your debug server logs to make sure the right url is being requested from the browser?

you can either have `r'^search/$'` and access the page param as `request.GET['page']` or you can pass in the param to your view function like `url(r'^search/(?P<page>\d+)/$` which would mean search would take 2 params request and then page.  If passing in the page param you need to change your form URL to be

```
<form method="GET" id="searchForm" action="/search/1">
```

Instead of having page be a GET param

I don't see anything wrong with your syntax for any of the urls you've listed.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view

If you are using `url(r'^search/(?P<page>\d+)/$'` make sure that search takes a variable named page as a second argument.  It is important to learn how to use the debugger too.

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` (or even better ipdb!),  Drop that in your view to see if its hitting, If its not hitting check dev server to see what url is actually being requested.

Comment: When I say describe I mean what should my `URL` look like? `url(r'^search/(what else here?)','ps.views.search')`

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'll try them out.

Comment: @reos, you can either have `r'^search/$'` and access the `page` param as `request.GET['page']` or you can pass in the param to your view function like `url(r'^search/(?P<page>\d+)/$` which would mean search would take 2 params `request` and then `page`.  I don't see anything wrong with your syntax for any of the veiws you've listed.

Comment: I've added the `search.py` for the eventuality of other problems.

Comment: Obviously I've went for the simple view and I'm trying to access the data with `request.GET['q_word'], but I get this in the `pdb` output `(Pdb) request.GET['q_word']
*** MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'q_word' not found in <QueryDict: {u'page': [u'1']}>"`

Comment: @reos, so your url is being hit fine!! thats good. and you are getting `page` in your GET dictionary.  So now if you remove the `import pdb` it look slike verything should work fine!

Comment: But the search no longer works.. nothing happens. On a, hopefully short, note.. How do I access the searched word? `request.GET['q_word']` ?

Comment: @reos, ooh ok i see your issue.  When you are submitting the form with a search term is q_word being appended to the url? What does django runserver log say?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10705/discussion-between-reos-and-dm03514)