# No data is sent with GET method

Tags: html, django, forms, search, pagination

I'm trying to use Pagination in my simple search and display application written in Django.

I've followed the tutorial on [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/pagination/) from Djangoproject but there is no data being sent to the server.

I've used `pdb.set_trace()` to view the output of the code, and the `GET` dictionary is empty.

Here is the code in the template and the `URLs` file:

**results.html:**

```
<form method="GET" id="searchForm" action="/search/">
        <input type="text" id="billSearched" name="q_word">
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Look for" %}">
</form>
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$','ps.views.bills',name="bills"),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^search/','ps.views.search',name="search"),)
```

and the view that works with this, **search.py:**

```
def search(request):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    searchTerm = request.GET.get('q_word')
    if searchTerm == None:
        searchTerm = "test"
    found_bills = Bill.objects.filter(name__icontains = searchTerm)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(found_bills,25)
    try:
        current_page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        current_page = paginator.page(1)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        current_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request,'results.html',{"results":current_page,"term": searchTerm})
```

Why is there no data being sent? I have read other posts as well and the solutions there didn't work for me. They suggested to access the 'q_word' value in the GET dictionary with either `request.GET.get('q_word')` or with `request.GET['q_word']` and by their answers it should work, but for me it doesn't.

Where is my mistake? Thank you very much in advance!

**UPDATE:**

```
[02/May/2012 14:03:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 39694
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/radu/projects/psdemo/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/home/radu/projects/psdemo/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/home/radu/projects/psdemo/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 403, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/home/radu/projects/psdemo/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 467, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/home/radu/projects/psdemo/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 385, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % http_date()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59087)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/radu/projects/psdemo/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 570, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you have `?q_word=...` in your URL on `search` page?

Comment: Make sure that after you submit your form the URL ends with `?q_word=search_term`

Comment: No, nothing is appended to the URL. I've recently made a Udacity tutorial where that works, but here it doesn't.

Comment: @reos The URL must end with `?q_word=search_term`

Comment: @JosvicZammit Do you suggest I modify the `URLs` file?

Comment: @reos I added an answer below.

Comment: @reos  have you tried this in multiple different browsers? Ie, Firefox, Chrome?

Comment: @dm03514 Yes, still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that query parameters are not being appended to the end of the URL when you submit. I suggest you use this syntax for the form:

```
<form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="/search/">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="billSearched" name="q_word">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "Look for" %}">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This should make your URL end with `?q_word=search_term` when you submit the form.

`urls.py` looks fine.

Comment: Error: `Cannot use None as a query value`. It seems data still isn't going through. And btw, the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/`, nothing else appended.

Comment: @reos The problem is that the [QueryString](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is not being appended to your URL. If it were you would receive it within your view's `request` object. There is something wrong in the form syntax, is the `trans` tag working properly? What if you remove the `trans`? Just experimenting...

Comment: Exactly, I can see that, but I'm trying to figure out if it's a problem with the code or not. I'm trying to narrow it down..

Comment: @reos It's a problem with the form; check your HTTP responses when submitting. Is it being rewritten (subsequently losing the querystring)?

Comment: How can I see if the HTTP is being rewritten?

Comment: I get a really big error in my terminal. I'll print the code under my question.

Comment: @reos You get that error every time you submit? That's some config error, on which I'm clueless :/

Comment: No, I get that error when I load the first page. When I submit a form I get `[02/May/2012 14:09:33] "GET /search/ HTTP/1.1" 500 87831`.. I'm assuming it has something to do with the first page. The first page loads, but the log is what you see updated in my question.

Comment: @reos The `500` is the internal server error, as expected. Can't figure out why the query parameters are not appended to the URL. That is your problem.

Comment: @reos Problem is that query parameters are not being appended to the end of the URL when you submit; it's either in the HTML or *maybe* some middleware that's swallowing the querystring? Not sure, sorry.