# Use Answers of HTML Form In Link to Submit

Tags: html, forms, parameters, hyperlink, submit

I was hoping someone could help me with submitting the answers to an HTML form as parameters of a link.  So for example, lets say the form looked like this:

```
Name: _______
Question: ______
```

Then, when the user types their answers, and hits submit, I want the answers to be placed as parameters of the link so that if the user types:

```
Name: Joe Smith
Question: How do I win?
```

When the user then presses submit, a link that looks like the following would be submitted:

```
https://myurl.com/Submit.asp?Name=Joe%20Smith&Question=How%20do%20I%20win?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear)  ,refer link

```
      method="GET"
```

more genrilize,

```
   <form action="url" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="" /> 
    <input type="text" name="Question" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" /> 
   </form>
```

So when you submitthe [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) it will automatically build the querystring and append it to url.

go through ***submitting form*** [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format)

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!  One more quick question - when my link submits with the values in the input fields, it makes the spaces "+" rather than "%20".  Any idea how to make the space encoding "%20"? I need that for my link to submit.

Comment: glad it helped you, and + is valid [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding), you get actual value by parsing it in your code

Comment: Ah yes I see...the issue was with something else I was doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Method type GET for your form