# Get query string values when submitting a form...MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC3 app, if i type in a query string value in the url and hit enter, I can get the value i typed:

```
localhost:34556/?db=test
```

My default action which will fire:

```
public ActionResult Index(string db)
```

The variable db has "test" in it.

Now, i need to submit a form and read the query string value, but when I submit the form via jQuery:

```
       $('#btnLogOn').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
             document.forms[0].submit();
         });
```

And the following is the form i'm sending:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Home", new { id="form1" }, FormMethod.Post))
```

Heres the action:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(LogOnModel logOnModel, string db)
    {
        string dbName= Request.QueryString["db"];
     }
```

The variable dbName is null because Request.QueryString["db"] is null, so is the variable db being passed in and i dont know why. Can someone help me get a query string variable after a form is submitted? Thanks

Comment: Query string will not be visible in a form post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear

Comment: Thanks for replying, then what is my alternative? I have to keep the query string btw

Comment: The alternative is to use the query string in the GET to populate a hidden input in a form.  Then the hidden input will post in with a submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have something like

Controllers:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LogIn(string dbName)
{
    LogOnViewModel lovm = new LogOnViewModel();
    //Initalize viewmodel here
    Return view(lovm);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(LogOnViewModel lovm, string dbName)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        //You can reference the dbName here simply by typing dbName (i.e) string test = dbName;
        //Do whatever you want here. Perhaps a redirect?
    }
    return View(lovm);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class LogOnViewModel
{
    //Whatever properties you have.
}
```

Edit: Fixed it up for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. This looks very similar to what im doing now. Where is the logic to get the value from the query string?

Comment: Err, the point of this method was that you don't have the value in the query string, you just assign it to your viewmodel inside the form.  Something like @Html.Textboxfor(model => model.dbName, etc.).  If you really want to put it in the URL (SEO purposes?) I think you can add a parameter in the @using(Html.BeginForm("LoginForm", "Home", new {.id = "form1", .dbName = YourFormFieldValueHere}, FormMethod.Post))

Comment: Err, my question was how do i get the query string value? Not any alternate ways. If i could go another route i would. But business rules say we use query string and i dont own the company. Thanks anyway

Comment: Try my edit.  The comments under the HTTPPost part should allow you to access the dbName part of the URL.  You don't need to do a Request.  Simply set whatever var you want equal to dbName.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using POST the data you are looking for is in `Request.Form` instead of `Request.QueryString`.

Comment: Thaks for replying, but Request.Form["db"] is null too.

Answer (score 2):

As @ThiefMaster♦ said, in a POST you cannot have the query string, never the less if you don't wan't to serialize your data to an specific object you can use the `FormCollection Object` which allows you to get all the form elements pass by post to the server

For example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    string dbName= formCollection["db"];

}
```

Comment: Will the FormCollection object have my logon information? the model being passed in has username/password etc..

Comment: It Contains all the elements that you had passed in the form, if your logon information in inside of the form, it will be on the formCollection