# How to pass a parameter in URL on a form submit in Struts2

Tags: java, url, struts2, struts, parameter-passing

I am doing a project in Struts2 where I need of setting a parameter in URL like user parameter in below link.

I want this parameter to be passed when I click a form submit button and not any links separately. I know how to do this with `<s:url>` but that way I need to create a link instead of form submit.

Can someone please help me with a code sample how to do this?
I know there's a way to do it with HTML or Struts1 but how to do it with Struts2? If there is a way to do this in `struts.xml`, please explain with an example.

```
<form action="/example/xyz.action?user=george" method="POST">
```

Comment: Why don't you store your value in a hidden field? It will be submitted automatically , when you submit the form.

Comment: There are a lot of ways for this. Just go with the hidden field like Shashank said, it is the neatest.

Comment: Do you want this parameter to be passed every time? Or why do you want to do this in `struts.xml`?

Comment: @user1819548 I was passing parameters via form actions. Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
<s:form action="xyz.action" method="GET">
    <s:hidden name="user" value="george"/>
    // other fields
</s:form>
```

`method="GET"` will show your parameter on the url, `<s:hidden name="user" value="george"/>` will take your parameter.

here is also an example for you [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-shidden-hidden-value-example/)

Comment: This is as close as it gets to the correct solution. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear.

**TLTR**: by html standards there should be no query param in action attribute of form tag.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible if you use `<s:url>` and `<s:form>` tags.

```xhtml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<s:url id="xyzUrl" action="xyz" includeContext="false">
  <s:param name="user" value="george"/>
</s:url>
<s:form name="xyzForm" action="%{xyzUrl}" method="POST">
```