# Append a query string with action in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, struts2, ognl

I am appending the parameters with action but I am getting an exception of on my Struts 2 page.

```
PWC6212: equal symbol expected
```

Below is my action with appended parameters code which is to be submitted.

```
action="MyAction.action?id=<%=request.getParameter("id")%>&name=<%=request.getParameter("name")%>&age=<%=request.getParameter("age")%>&num=<%=request.getParameter("num")%>"
```

Is the above is the syntax problem? If not then how can we set the parameters as a query string with action?

Comment: please post your whole usecase, at lease the `tag` people cannot understand you with your snippet.

Comment: basically I am appending the querystring with action which is to be submitted but my struts2 page shows an exception "equal symbol expected".

Comment: @Java_NewBie Use struts tags.

Answer (score 3):

You *should* not use Scriptlets (`<%= %>`)

And, if `action` is an attribute of a Struts tag (like `<s:form>`), you **can't** use scriptlets, you should use `OGNL`.

Please refer to this question: [Struts 2 s:select tag dynamic id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639898/struts-2-sselect-tag-dynamic-id) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Assumed the `action` attribute is used with the `<form` tag. Then the construction

```
<form name="MyAction.action" action="upload?id=<%=request.getParameter("id")%>&name=<%=request.getParameter("name")%>&age=<%=request.getParameter("age")%>&num=<%=request.getParameter("num")%>" method="POST">
```

should work with the current context. But in your case given error message (`Exception Name: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: equal symbol expected` is occurred when `<s:form` tag is used. So, you cannot use this url in the action attribute. This attribute should contain the plain action name that would be used to find your action.

> "How we set parameters as a querystring?"

Actually we do it with `<s:param` tag. For example, when using hyperlinks

```
<s:a action="MyAction">
   <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"/>
   <s:param name="name" value="%{name}"/>
</s:a>
```

But this construction doesn't work with `<s:form` tag, unless you applying a special syntax as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373760/how-to-pass-a-parameter-in-url-on-a-form-submit-in-struts2/13380998#13380998) answer and you definitely want to get these parameters if you do in the action

```
String quesyString = request.getQueryString();
```

and this string should not be empty.

However, this usecase is rarely applied, If you don't have a reason to get parameters in such way then as alternative you always can use `<s:hidden` fields to contain the values of the parameters. For example

```
<s:form action="MyAction" method="POST">
    <s:hidden name="id" value="%{id}"/>
    <s:hidden name="name" value="%{name}"/>
</s:form>
```

These values are passed as a parameters and initialize the action attributes after `params` interceptor worked. You could also get this parameters directly from the request as

```
Map<String, String[]> params = (Map<String, String[]>)request.getParameterMap();
```

However, the more convenient way to do this  in your action is to implement `ParameterAware`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @AndreaLigios mentioned, you should use Struts2 specified EL, check out the [Document](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/jsp.html) here.

If you are using `<s:url/>`, check out [Document](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/url.html) please for more information.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<s:url value="MyAction.action">
    <s:param name="id" value="%{#parameters.id}" />
    <s:param name="name" value="%{#parameters.name}" />
    <s:param name="age" value="%{#parameters.age}" />
    <s:param name="num" value="%{#parameters.num}" />
</s:url>
```