# Pass url parameter to submit action Struts2 and display url result with same parameter

Tags: java, struts2

I'm using struts2 for front end framework and found this issue which need to be resolved. So I view the page with edit privilege for this url

```
 [CONTEXT]/getUser.do?userId=1
```

But when I click Submit button, it seems struts render my request uri to getUser.do without any URL parameter. It also displayed in my result url

```
 [CONTEXT]/getUser.do
```

[From this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373760/how-to-pass-a-parameter-in-url-on-a-form-submit-in-struts2) I knew I can use struts hidden tag. But using that tag will not change the result URL. I want the URL parameter passed to java action, as well as change the URL result.

If I using s:url tag, it need to know the value beforehand (is it?).

```
<s:url id="xyzUrl" action="xyz" includeContext="false"><s:param name="user" value="george"/></s:url>
```

If using `s:url` tag, how can I pass dynamic value given by url parameter(in url browser) to the value argument of struts url tag? And can this solution resolve both of view mode(display page in the first time) and submit mode(submit the displayed page)?

Comment: What do you want to know from [that SO solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373760/how-to-pass-a-parameter-in-url-on-a-form-submit-in-struts2)?

Comment: @RomanC from that solution, the url parameter will be added to url string only for GET method. While I need it in POST method also. My example above, if I set the success result to  the same url, it wont write the url parameter to the url string.

Comment: I didn't use GET in my answer.

Comment: Ah you're the one who answer using s:url. It doesnt work for me. Do we have to include " <constant name="struts.url.includeParams" value="none" />" in our struts.xml?
I'll update the question to give more info

Comment: @RomanC actually it worked! I misread your solution when in form tag we fill action value with %{id value in s:url tag}

But, tag s:url always write the url in my page(as content in my html body). How can I delete this text?

Comment: Struts used `id` attribute in previous versions, in newer versions you should use `var` instead.

Comment: if I use "var", the parameter will not included again. With "id" it worked @RomanC but the url text keep displayed in my page. 
' <s:url var="planlist" escapeAmp="false">
</s:url>
<s:form id="form1" action="%{planlist}" method="post"> '

Comment: I don't see where the url parameter is applied.

Comment: @RomanC Because I simply want to include the url parameter in GET request. For example, my GET request is [CONTEXT]/getUser.do?userId=10. And then on that page I do submit (POST) process, then by default the previous userId will not included in next url. After I click submit, the url will automatically be [CONTEXT]/getUser.do , without userId=10

Comment: Bu you didn't include any parameter in the `url`tag. Parameters are created via `param` tag.