# Query string lost from a submit button

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I am new to both web application and the play framework, and the problem I am asking might be very naive. However, I googled around for a little while and couldn't find a good answer to it, so please bear with me.

First, my platform is play-2.1.1 + java 1.6 + OS X 10.8.3.

A short version of the problem: I have a form of submit button with action="hello?id=100". However, when I click the button, the request being sent seems to be `hello?` rather than `hello?id=100`. The action for this request expects the parameter `id`, so I get an error for `hello?`.

Here is the full setup.

conf/routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /hello                      controllers.Application.hello(id: Long)
```

app/controllers/Application.java:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render());
    }

    public static Result hello(Long id) {
        return ok("Hello, No. " + id);
    }

}
```

app/views/index.scala.html

```
This is an index page.

<form name="helloButton" action="hello?id=100" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Hello">
</form>
```

According to the play documentation, the `id` is supposed to be extracted from the query string `?id=100`. However, when I click the submit button, the request becomes `hello?` rather than `hello?id=100`, and thus I get an error like this:

> For request 'GET /hello?' [Missing parameter: id]

Can someone tell me why this is happening, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When submitting a GET form, the query string is removed from the action URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/when-submitting-a-get-form-the-query-string-is-removed-from-the-action-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the form:

```
<form name="helloButton" action="hello?id=100" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Hello">
</form>
```

As the form method is set to get, it's changing the query string. `method="get"` tells the browser to add the contents of the form to the query string which means the current query string gets removed.

You can add the ID as a hidden field in the form like this:

```
<form name="helloButton" action="hello" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="100">
    <input type="submit" value="Hello">
</form>
```

That will tell the browser to add the hidden field to the query string resulting in `hello?id=100`. Alternatively you could change the form method to POST.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. Problem solved. I went for the post solution.