# URL's query-string portion is getting cut of when used as a link in a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

I have the following code to link a button to a specific URL.

```
stage_link = " 'http://limitless-scrubland-2940.herokuapp.com/game/game.html?stageid=5' "
<form action=stage_link method='get'> 
    <button>Play stage!</button>
</form>
```

The button renders fine, but it links to: "http://limitless-scrubland-2940.herokuapp.com/game/game.html"

Why is it that the query-string portion (`?stageid=5`) gets truncated off? Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. `<form action` cannot be a `$_GET` query. Use a hidden field and test against it, if you must submit a form:

```
<form method='get' action='http://limitless-scrubland-2940.herokuapp.com/game/game.html' method='get'>
  <input type='hidden' name='stageid' value='5' />
  <input type='submit' value='Play stage!' name='playstage' id='playstage' />
</form>
```

Now test for `$_GET['stageid']` on your PHP page.

For your purpose, however you may just need:

```
<a id='playstage' href='http://limitless-scrubland-2940.herokuapp.com/game/game.html?stageid=5'>
  Play stage!
</a>
```

Comment: I'm not actually using PHP, but can you explain how to user that input<> tag with my button?

Comment: `<button type='button'>text</button>` and `<input type='button' value='text' />` are virtually the same. A button does not actually even submit a form unless its `type='submit'`, which may be the default `type`, depending on your Browser, unless you are using JavaScript to submit your form. My second example is probably what you want, if you have no need to submit the form. You can always style an `<a>` tag, like: `#playstage{text-decoration:none;}`, adding padding and other CSS features to make it look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method='get'> 
    <button>Play stage!</button>
</form>
<script>
document.forms[0].action= "http://limitless-scrubland-2940.herokuapp.com/game/game.html"
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = 'stageid';
input.value = '5';
document.forms[0].appendChild(input);
</script>
```

See [submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear) on why.