# php button parameter gets lost

Tags: php, button

I am creating a button in php and want to call a php with parameter when clicked:

```
echo '<form method="get" action="./ash.php?q=Y"    >';
echo '<button type="submit"    >QUERY</button>';
echo '</form>';
```

When I click on the button, ash.php gets indeed called, but the q parameter has been 'forgotten' in the process.
How can that be?

Comment: Why don't you put a hidden field with the name q and the value of Y

Comment: because ash.php may be called with or without parameter

Comment: That's actually a feature, not a bug, you're not supposed to form an `action` attribute that way.

Comment: so, test your parameters into ash.php : `$q = (isset($_GET['q')) ?: '';`

Comment: possible duplicate of [submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '<form method="get" action="./ash.php"    >';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="q" value="Y" />';
echo '<button type="submit"    >QUERY</button>';
echo '</form>';
```