# why url is not constructed as expected in GET request?

Tags: web-applications, browser, httprequest, get-request

I have  below form in html page

```
<form name="input" action="sayHello1.jsp?param1=test1" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i enter the value "test" in text box and submit it.

I expect to see the submitted URL in browser as

```
http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/sayHello1.jsp?param1=test1&user=test
```

but i see the url as

```
http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/sayHello1.jsp?user=test
```

why so ?

Comment: What browser are you using? This is not related to Java.

Comment: I'd use a hidden value anyway, but that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the form appears to be rewriting the query string (not merging it).  To get your desired behavior add a `<input type="hidden" name="param1" value="test1">` to your form, and don't try to add values to the action URL.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9882750/1168588), we should expect this behavior.

> So, your browser will trash the existing "?..." part of your URI and replace it with a new one based on your form.

Comment: But this is true for Get request only not for POST. Right?

Comment: Right.  I think Sotirios' answer (and the specification, and the answer linked in my answer) is clear on the point.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm) states

> When a form element form is submitted from an element submitter
>   (typically a button), optionally with a scripted-submit flag set, the
>   user agent must run the following steps:
>
> [...]
>
> - Let query be the result of encoding the form data set using the
>     application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm, interpreted as a
>     US-ASCII string.
> - Let destination be a new URL that is equal to the action except that
>     its  component is replaced by query (adding a U+003F QUESTION
>     MARK character (?) if appropriate).

Basically, it replaces the existing query string with a new one generated from the form parameters.

Your browser is following the specification.

Comment: +1. Interestingly, the HTML 4 spec says *If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.* That would obviously result in an incorrect URL if the action already contains a query string, and I guess the behavior is undefined in that case. The HTML5 spec is clearer.

Comment: but with post request i see the correct url i.e "http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/sayHello1.jsp?param1=test1"

Comment: @user3222249 If you follow the link, there are different behaviors for GET and POST. For POST, the browser leaves it as is.