# Simple way to add a parameter to current URL in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, url, forms

On a particular page in my website, there are a variety of potential URL parameters:

```
http://www.example.com/my_webpage?at=2014-01-01&page=5
```

Now I want a simple way to add a parameter to that like this:

```
http://www.example.com/my_webpage?at=2014-01-01&page=5&records=100
```

So I tried the following HTML with embedded Ruby:

```
<form action="<%= request.original_url %>" method="get"># of records <input type="text" name="records"/></form>
```

The problem is the resulting page that opens is:

```
http://www.example.com/my_webpage?records=100
```

Essentially, the old parameters get wiped away. What's an easy way to retain them? I could loop through the `params` hash and add `hidden_tag`s (I'd have to selectively exclude params not part of the request params), but I would expect with such a common use case scenario there's a better easier way.

Comment: Apparently, you will have to use hidden_tags. There is not better way. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear)

Comment: Is there an easy way to iterate through the request params in Rails? I mean the `params` hash contains the request params as well as parameters in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

While there isn't an easy Rails way of doing this automatically, Rails does provide access to the request parameters through the `request.query_parameters` hash. So I simply needed to add this in the form:

```
<% request.query_parameters.each do |key, val|%>
  <input type="hidden" name="<%= key %>" value="<%= val %>"/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I suggest to use `params` instead of `request.query_parameters`.

Comment: I don't want all the params though, only those in the URL of the current page