# I do not know how to write out a URL encoded query string

Tags: javascript, html, button

I actually asked a very similar question yesterday, but am sure I did not ask properly. The suggestions I received were all very helpful, but unfortunately, JavaScript is VERY foreign to me and I have a terrible time understanding how to write JavaScript.

I have what is no doubt a very easy basic JavaScript problem that somebody in the know could probably answer in minutes. It has taken me about 2 days so far, and counting ...

I have a client that will be using a HTML email to send out to their clients, within that email there will be a CTA to send them to a financial investments calculator. Once on that page the end user will have the option to either fill out the calculator, or to click another CTA sending them to contact an advisor.

It is this button that is causing me grief. The client would like me to use a GET 'function' to fill in the URL encoded query string. I do not know how to write this out. I've been Googling this issue and when I find solutions, as were also suggested yesterday by other users, I do not know how to write out the snippet. I know this may seem like I am trying to get other people to d my work for me, but trust me I've been searching long and hard for this solution.

So if anybody can help, I really need your answer/suggestion "dumbed" down.

This is what my client sent me ...

```
This is the URL that the maximizer calculator calls when the CTA button is clicked passing back the RID to us.
http://responsetoday.com/jointventure-ecomm/purl54pki3r.aspx?rid=TST1232544
```

This is what I had come up with ...

```
<form action="http://responsetoday.com/jointventure-ecomm/purl54pki3r.aspx?rid=TST1232544" target="_blank" method="get">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Talk to a Sales Representative">
   <button type="submit">Talk to a sales rep</button>
</form>
```

Unfortunately, the way I have written it "hard codes" the response after 'rid=', this is not good and is not working. I'm sorry for the long winded post for what is probably a very easy fix, but I wanted to share as much detail as possible. Thanks to everybody for your help in advance.

Comment: So what happens when you submit the form?

Comment: Where do you want to get the `rid` value from?

Comment: Why two submit buttons?

Comment: @Juhana Nothing. Right now it goes to a blank page. What should happen is it should go to another page that will alert the advisor somebody is trying to contact them.

Comment: @plalx I think I wrote that part out wrong and may have included other things I was trying. Sorry.

Comment: @Boann the rid value is coming from an externally supplied js file.

Comment: That URL looks fine as-is. Perhaps you can investigate further with your browser's developer tools; see what the HTTP request and response look like.

Comment: @Pointy hmmm, I think the problem is, the way I've written the code, from the supplied example from the client, is the portion after the rid= portion is essentially hardcoded. I believe the GET should "randomly" select the credentials of the stored advisors information.

Comment: @Frankie "externally supplied js file" ... That's not a good explanation at all. Please show what your inputs are and what output you expect to generate from them.

Comment: @Boann hmmm, okay lemme see if I can figure that request out. Please forgive me, when it comes to JavaScript it's really rather embarassing how inept I am.

Comment: @Frankie, Focus on the problem and the important détails. Problem: "dynamically populate the `rid` in the URL". That requires a few détails. How can we access the `rid` value? In which context the HTML form gets generated? Is it generated by a server-side process? Is it a static HTML page?

Comment: @plalx it is a static HTML page. Here is the staging URL for the calculator http://client-staging.info/KFF/kff/index-eng.html?http%3A%2F%2Ficanrespond.ca%2Fkff-ecomm%2Fpurl3r.aspx%3Frid%3DTST1234 ... At the bottom of the page is where I will be adding the CTA button.

Comment: @Frankie Ok, but that still doesn't explain where the `rid` comes from...

Comment: @plalx hmmm, okay I'm gonna hafta try and figure this out ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="salesrepform" target="_blank" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Talk to a Sales Representative">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('salesrepform').action =
    unescape(location.href.match(/\?(.*)/)[1]);
</script>
```

I changed the form method to 'post', as a blunt workaround for the fact that otherwise, the form [drops the query string from the action URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear), so that even the hard-coded URL does not work.

After that the script reads the part of the current page's URL after the `?`, unescapes it, and sets it as the form action. Based on the URL you provided, I think that's what you want.