# Get variable lost in form action on submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

When this is form is submit by the `onchange` event it is not keeping the get variable `view`. Any ideas why this might be happening? On submit this is the url it goes to, `index?month=February&year=2014`

```
<form action="index?view=list" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" style="margin:20px;">
    <select name="month" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear) - specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear#answer-9882750) from xyphoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a hidden input field inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="list" />
```