# form action parameter not working

Tags: html, forms, get, submit, action

```
<a href="index.php?page=test"> Test </a>
<br><br>
<form action="index.php?page=test">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter text"> </input>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Why is the  link working correctly  while the form gets me the url http://example.com/index.php? in the adress bar of the browser?
Every parameter i define in the action attribute is getting cut off

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When submitting a GET form, the query string is removed from the action URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/when-submitting-a-get-form-the-query-string-is-removed-from-the-action-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use this code.

```
<a href="index.php?page=test"> Test </a>
<br><br>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter text"> </input>
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="test">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are submitting a GET form. The data in the form will be expressed as a query string and replace the one in the URL in the action.

Move the data from the query string into hidden inputs inside the form.