# button_to current link with params that not showing in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In `http://localhost:3000/services/1` I have a button to the current page with params:

```
 <%= button_to table.seats, service_path(@service, table_id: table.id), method: :get, class=["btn"] %>
```

On page, I see correct:

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/services/1?table_id=3">
  <input class="btn" type="submit" value="2">
</form>
```

But in the `service_controller` I have a breakpoint and can not see the `params[:table_id] = 3`

```
(byebug) params
{"controller"=>"services", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"1"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

If I get the current absolute url in controller and obtain:

```
(byebug) request.original_url
"http://localhost:3000/services/1"
```

but the link in the button was:

```
action="/services/1?table_id=3"
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include a query string in the `action` attribute of a form. You need to pass the table id in a hidden input.

[submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear)

Comment: You probably want to use the more standard [Rails form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) instead of `button_to`.