# How can I pass a second parameter in a search form?

Tags: php, forms, search, get, url-parameters

I have a search field, that creates the URL for example: `mypage.com/action.php?srch=rabbit`

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <form action="action.php" method="get" role="search" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input style="margin-top:0px" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suchen..." name="srch" id="srch">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

But I need to create a link that is `mypage.com/action.php?id=12&srch=rabbit`

So I changed this line:

```
<form action="<?php echo "action.php?id=".$id; ?>" method="get" role="search" style="margin-top:20px">
```

But unfortunately the result is still: `mypage.com/action.php?srch=rabbit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the required additional field in a hidden input.

```
<input name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" type="hidden">
```

Code will look like this.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <form action="action.php" method="get" role="search" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input style="margin-top:0px" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suchen..." name="srch" id="srch">
            <input name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" type="hidden">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You could've just copied my input instead of posting the wrong one.

Comment: Yup, I was wrong first. Thanks for showing the error!

Comment: More info from a previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear

Answer (score 2):

Add a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```