# Why Can't I Use & in Action Form

Tags: forms, action

First of all sorry for my English.

I'm trying to use "&" in the URL of form action but somehow it's not working.

Exm;

```
<form action="rental-quote.php?step=2&" method="get">
```

When I submit this way I get data like this;

> rental-quote.php?date_from=18-06-2016&hour_from=00&minutes_from=00&date_to=19-06-2016&hour_to=00&minutes_to=00&pickup_id=1&return_id=1

As you can see

> step=2&

not shown.

What do I have to do, I searched and can't find aything.

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear). I.e. you need a tag in the form like `<input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" />` instead of adding it to the `action`.

Comment: Thank you so much! How on earth I couldn't find that question while I search...