# Post and get method not show correct url

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="../index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=3" method = "get">
  <input type="hidden" name='form[Name]' value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and i need this result:

```
http://localhost/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=3&form[Name]=1
```

but i get this result:

```
http://localhost/index.php?form%5BName%5D=1
```

where is the problem?

Comment: You might want to add two more hidden fields to the form with name option, formId and values com_rsform and 3 respectively

Comment: yea thanks !! that was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be expected behavior regarding form actions when a combination of `action` URL parameters and form fields are present, and at the moment I'm not finding anything in a spec which tells otherwise.

The practical solution seems to be to just put the values you want in the form itself:

```
<form action="../index.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name='option' value="com_rsform">
  <input type="hidden" name='formId' value="3">
  <input type="hidden" name='form[Name]' value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear)

The GET parameters of "action" are overwrited by the form. So, the answer of David is correct.

Other solution: make a POST form and keep your URL ;)