# Get request.params via an html form?

Tags: html, node.js, express

This question title was edited. The original title was **"How can I submit a string in a form and have it applied as a request parameter in the url?"**.

---

Think of a simple server where a string is received as a route parameter, e.g. with `localhost:3000/hello` it serves a page containing 'hello'.

This is easily implemented, here is a simple express server doing that:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/:string", function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.params.string);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Is it possible to supply the string via a form?

Answer (score 0):

- Assigning a value to *req.params* via an html form is not inherently feasible.
  Forms assign values easily to *req.query* instead.
- Definitions for req,params and req.query described in Express [4.x API Reference](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html):

> req.params
> This property is an object containing properties mapped to the named route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route /user/:name, then the “name” property is available as req.params.name. This object defaults to {}.
>
> req.query
> This property is an object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route. If there is no query string, it is the empty object, {}.

- [Arjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84237/arjan)'s answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear) cites *hidden type inputs* which could be helpful in certain use cases.