# Razor Pages, form page handler not working with GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a small ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project. I'm making a simple list display page with a basic search functionality. In my model, I have 4 page handlers (2 of them are added for debug purposes):

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    Posting = await _context.Postings
        .Include(p => p.ItemDetails).Include(p => p.Owner).ToListAsync();
}

public async Task OnPostAsync()
{
    Posting = await _context.Postings
        .Include(p => p.ItemDetails).Include(p => p.Owner).ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<PageResult> OnGetSearchAsync(String search)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        search = search.Trim();
        Posting = await _context.Postings.Where(p => p.ItemDetails.ItemName.Contains(search)).ToListAsync();
    }
    return Page();
}

public async Task<PageResult> OnPostSearchAsync(String search)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        search = search.Trim();
        Posting = await _context.Postings
            .Where(p => p.ItemDetails.ItemName.Contains(search)).ToListAsync();
    }
    return Page();
}
```

When the form specifies `method="post"` with `asp-page-handler="search"`, the form calls the correct handler (`OnPostSearchAsync(String search)`). However, when the form specifies `method="get"` with `asp-page-handler="search"`, the form calls the wrong handler (`OnGetAsync()`). Is this intended? If so how can i call a custom handler while using the `GET` method? Maybe using a custom handler isn't necessary but i think i should be able to if i choose to.

Here is the relevant code in `.cshtml` file:

```html
<div id="posting_search_bar_container">
    <form method="get" asp-page-handler="search">
        <input type="text" name="search" />
        <input type="submit" value="Ara" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="posting_list_container">
    @if (Model.Posting != null)
    {
        @foreach (var posting in Model.Posting)
        {
            <partial name="./Partials/_Posting" model="new Pages.Postings.Partials.PostingModel(posting);" />
        }
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In terms of *why* this happens, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9882750/2630078) should explain what's going on here. Essentially, `asp-page-handler` sets up an action URL that includes `?handler=search`, which then gets trashed by the browser for GET requests.

In terms of workarounds, I see two:

**Option 1** - [Customise the routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes-1)

Taken straight from the docs, you can modify your page directive slightly in the .cshtml in order to customise the routing:

```
@page "{handler?}"
```

This option states that for the given page, use an extra segment for specifying the handler name, rather than setting it as a query-string parameter. That means your calls will change from e.g. `/PageName?handler=handlerName` to `/PageName/Handler`. The `?` in the `{handler?}` expression from the code-snippet simply states that a handler name is optional and will therefore default to e.g. `OnGetAsync`.

This option works because there is no longer a query-string value for the browser to trash, but yet the handler name *is* captured within the route itself.

**Option 2** - Use a hidden input

When submitting a form using GET to a defined action URL, the browser builds up a query-string from the controls that live within the form. This gives the option for adding a new hidden input field to the form:

```html
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="handler" value="search" />
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Ara" />
</form>
```

Here, I've removed the `asp-page-handler` and added a hidden input that will end up setting the query-string value of `handler` to `search`, which builds up a query-string that will match for `OnGetSearchAsync` in your example.