# Razor Pages - Run a server side method NOT using post

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

In Razor pages ASP.NET Core, how do I do a basic onclick event for a button which is of type button?

Do I need to wire up an AJAX GET request to get the below "Resend Code" button to work? There is plenty of chatter about OnPost this and that.. but I don't want to post.

Can't be this hard?

```html
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

    <div class="form-group-item">
        <label asp-for="Input.TwoFactorCode"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.TwoFactorCode" class="input" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.TwoFactorCode"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group-item">
        <label class="margin-0" asp-for="Input.RememberMachine">
            <input asp-for="Input.RememberMachine" />
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMachine)
        </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" asp-page-handler="ResendCode" class="btn btn-light">Resend Code</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, the button won't do anything. You can use JavaScript to intercept the button click and then fire a `get` request using AJAX (jQuery example below):

```
$('.btn.btn-light').on('click', function(){
    $.get('?handler=ResendCode', data, function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: don't forget to add the OnGet prefix to the ResendCode function on your page !

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the button to use `formmethod="get"`:

```
<button type="submit" formmethod="get" asp-page-handler="ResendCode" class="btn btn-light">Resend Code</button>
```

Note, this will only work for buttons that have `type="submit"` or `type="image"` (other `type`-values don't cause the form to submit). Also it's an HTML5 attribute.

*Reference:*

- https://html.com/attributes/input-formmethod/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formmethod

Comment: Nice idea, but it seems to remove the handler from the query string which means that the named handler isn't hit.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Maybe then this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50815280/1220550

Answer (score 0):

maybe try making your own custom handler methods other than OnPost() and OnGet()

Comment: He's got a custom (named) handler - `ResendCode`.