# Asp.net Core Razor Pages, page handler not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Can't call page handler methods.
in razor page

```
<a asp-page="/CreateNew">Link1</a>

<a asp-page="/CreateNew"  asp-page-handler="submit">Link1</a>
```

CreateNew.cshtml.cs:

```
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {            
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnGetSubmit()
    {            
        return Page();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Razor Pages, form page handler not working with GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815280/razor-pages-form-page-handler-not-working-with-get-method)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: In which folder is the createnew.cshtml file located?

Comment: Views/PersonalPage/Createnew.cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a razor page, you must put your file in the **pages** folder

Instead of **Views** Folder and your link will be as follows

```
<a asp-page="/PersonalPage/CreateNew">Link1</a>
```

And the startup file should be configured as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddRazorPages();
}


 ........

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the link and suggestion is not working.

Comment: Do your Folder Structure match the image I uploaded?