# ASP.NET MVC Core Tag Helper Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am having an issue using tag helpers in a form element. When I choose the "GET" HTTP method, the parameter for my Edit method in my Item controller won't get filled by the "hello" argument. However, when I choose the "POST" HTTP method, the parameter is filled correctly with "hello". Why is this happening?

```
<form asp-controller="Item" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-item="hello" method="get">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And here is the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(string item)
    {
        if (Request.Method == "GET")
        {
            ViewData["item"] = item;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with the `form` tag helper. When using HTML `form` tag, if your are using GET method, the browser will read the form element values and append that to the form `action` attribute value url following a `?`. So i assume your browser is removing your existing query string items for this purpose.  So consider moving that to an input element inside the form.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Edit" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="second"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Sending the existing querystring values from the `action` method attribute is not guaranteed to work.. Take look at [submitting a GET form with query string params and hidden params disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear)