# Pass RouteValues from Action to HTML BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im trying to pass asingle route value from my Action method to the HTML. I'm trying to pass a single token value that is being held in my url to another Action method.

***My Action method***

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.Username + ":" + user.Password)));

                HttpResponseMessage clientTask = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44324/api/Auth/LogIn");

                if (clientTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string txtBlock = await clientTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var tokenObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionAPI>(txtBlock);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;

                    Request.RouteValues["token"] = tokenObject.Token;

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", Request.RouteValues);
                }
                else
                    return View("LogInIndex", user);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("An Error has occured" + e);
            }
        }
```

***My HTML***

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Auth", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Log Out" />
            }

        </div>
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ListAll", "User", FormMethod.Get)) // <-- Trying to pass a route value for this form
            {
                <input type="submit" value="List All" />
            }

        </div>
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateIndex", "User", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Create a User" />
            }

        </div>
    </div>
```

The basic idea is to have a token that is stored in the URL and when a new request is passed to be sent with it and assigned to the headers for authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`ViewBag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#passing-data-to-views) which can passes a data to view, make some modifications in your code as follows：

1.**LogIn action** , pass the routevalue in `RedirectToAction` like:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { token=tokenObject.Token});
```

2.**Index action**, save the token in ViewBag

```
 ViewBag.Token = Request.Query["token"];
```

3.**Index view**, never use GET to send sensitive data! (will be visible in the URL),you could use a hidden input to send the data

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ListAll", "User", FormMethod.Get)) 
{
    <input hidden name="token" value="@ViewBag.Token"/>
    <input type="submit" value="List All" />
}
```

4.**ListAll action**, use a parameter to get the data

```
    public IActionResult ListAll(string token)
    { ... }
```

Reference:
[ASP.NET MVC Core Tag Helper Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892106/asp-net-mvc-core-tag-helper-issue/50892229#50892229)