# single query is double query in my url(js problem or symfony error)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, symfony

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" 
      name="keywords" value="{{ keywords }}">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cauta</button>
</form>
```

my url on first click http://localhost:8090/xxxkeywords=tu
on second click http://localhost:8090/xxx?keywords=tu&keywords=tu

Comment: after first submit your URL will be changed with query param, on the second click it will again add query param as you are submitting the form on the same page

Comment: That should not normally happen with a GET method form, submitting overwrites the existing query string - that has even been standardized with HTML5, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9882750/10955263 Feels like this is probably missing some important detail (JS interfering? URL rewriting of any kind in place?)

Comment: Have you tried to set `action` on your form?

Comment: action is the answer