# Is it possible to send params in a form URL

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I can send the param `x=y` in a form with a hidden field like this

```
<%= form_with(url: '/search', method: 'get') do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:x, 'y') %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to send params in the URL? The following doesn't work

```
<%= form_with(url: '/search?x=y', method: 'get') do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear), the query string that you might have in a HTML form `action` attribute will not taken into account.

Translated into your `form_for` problem, it means that the query string that you have in your `url:` are not taken into account.

Hence, your `hidden_field_tag` is the right solution for this problem.