# Using a form (method=GET) to pass parameters defined elsewhere

Tags: php, html, parameters, get, form-submit

This is such a simple question that I'm afraid I'm missing something basic, so feel free to shame me, but I'm stumped.

My goal: make a "continue" button that reloads the same page, but with an incremented ?Page= parameter that's visible to GET.

My current approach: define the new URL that should be loaded (this bit works)

```
$_SESSION['NextPage'] = $_SESSION['Page']+1; 
$_SESSION['NewURL'] = $_SESSION['CurrentFile'] . '?Page=' . $_SESSION['NextPage'];
// N.B: $_SESSION['CurrentFile'] just specifies the URL of the current page.
// Note also that there should ALWAYS be a ?Page= parameter in the URL, even if it evaluates to NaN or something weird.
```

Then, later on, a function is called that runs this code and creates a submit button.  The button is there, as expected, but it doesn't WORK as expected: code & details below.

```
echo "<tr><td><form action='" . $_SESSION['NewURL'] . "' method='GET'> <input type='submit' value='Continue'></form> </td></tr>";
```

The problem: When the form submits, it doesn't append any `?Page=` parameters to the URL, either in Chrome or Safari.  Is this because the Page parameter isn't specified inside this form??  If so, there must be a way around that, right?  `$_SESSION['NextPage']` is a session variable, for crying out loud!  Not to mention that when I echo `$_SESSION['NewURL']` inside the function, the info is accessible there, `?Page=2` and all. It's just not pushed to the URL. Unfortunately, the page is set up to display different content based on the value of `$_GET['Page']`, and now there's nothing there to control that process.

If I've just made a syntax error or something I'll be embarrassed but relieved. I just can't find it, and don't know where else to turn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable via a form (`GET` or `POST`) the simple way then just use a hidden form `input`

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['NextPage']; ?>">
```

Your form becomes:

```
echo "<tr><td>
<form action='" . $_SESSION['NewURL'] . "' method='GET'>
  <input type='hidden' name='page' value='" . $_SESSION['NextPage'] . "'>
  <input type='submit' value='Continue'>
</form>
</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks for this clever idea.  Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue.  Now at least I get a "?" at the end of the URL, but still nothing else. This is weird, right?

Comment: Change `type='hidden'` to `type='text'`, that will show you the value. If it is empty then `$_SESSION['NextPage']` is not properly set. Or else try typing a value directly in the input like "abc" your query string should contain `?page=abc`

Comment: My bad!  I reloaded the wrong file.  Yes, this solution works- thank you!  For my own education- would you mind explaining just WHY my original setup didn't work?

Comment: I did a little searching: read the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732371/what-happens-if-the-action-field-in-a-form-has-parameters

Comment: Again, thank you.  I searched long and hard as well, but never came across that post.