# django parameter via get not working while forming direct url

Tags: django, django-urls

**Base URL:**

```
path('api/product/',
include(('store.urls', 'store'),
namespace='api-product')),
```

**Store URL:**

```
path('invoice-pdf-get/',
invoice.InvoiceToPdf.as_view(),
name='invoice-pdf-get'),
```

**HTML:**

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="get" action="{% url 'api-product:invoice-pdf-get' %}?R={{ invoice.invoice_unique_number }}">
<input type="submit" value="Generate PDF">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit the button, I get the url in browser as:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/product/invoice-pdf-get/?
```

Where as expecting:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/product/invoice-pdf-get/?invoice_number=SOMEKEY
```

Though if I submit a hidden type input via form, I get the expected result
 but I was reading: [Daniel Roseman SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591525/is-it-possible-to-pass-query-parameters-via-djangos-url-template-tag). to pass parameter via `GET`.

Though inspect shows the URL (see image) but why am I not getting expected result?

[image: form url]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a form is submitted via GET, the values in the form are sent as the querystring. This *overrides* any querystring in the `action` URL. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732371/what-happens-if-the-action-field-in-a-form-has-parameters) for example.

You should put your value as a hidden input in the form itself.

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'api-product:invoice-pdf-get' %}">
  <input type="hidden" name="R" value="{{ invoice.invoice_unique_number }}">
  <input type="submit" value="Generate PDF">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things sir!