# PHP mixing POST and GET Requests to one page

Tags: php, forms, post, get

After reading:

- [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)
- [Mixing GET with POST - is it a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592418/mixing-get-with-post-is-it-a-bad-practice)

I understand, that GET is used to retrieve a page without changing the server and POST is used for things (insert, update, delete), that change the server.

Now I have written a page which is called with a GET request with parameter `StationNr` set. The user can fill a form and makes a POST request to the same page with parameter `Filter` set. But I don't want to miss the parameter `StationNr` thus I thought I give it into a hidden input field. But then the parameter `StationNr` is either in the `$_GET` variable (first call) or in the `$_POST` variable (second call). I can do something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['StationNr']))
    $snr = $_GET['StationNr'];
else if (isset($_POST['StationNr']))
    $nr = $_POST['StationNr'];
```

But I don't like this. Also I don't want to use `$_REQUEST['StationNr']` because of: [When and why should $_REQUEST be used instead of $_GET / $_POST / $_COOKIE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107683/when-and-why-should-request-be-used-instead-of-get-post-cookie)

I think this is a common issue but I haven't faced it yet because I'm a beginner in writing php pages. How did you solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It might not be the cleanest design, put you can certainly fire a POST request to an address to which you append a `?param=value&...` string to have both GET and POST.

Comment: The `$_REQUEST` badmouthing is unwarranted. With older setups it was subject to cookie fixation, which is often a usability, but not a security issue. Nevertheless it's intended as shortcut for exactly that (GET/POST input parameters as aliases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can use ?foo=bar to push GET values in a POST request, I'd suggest checking the request method instead:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
<form method="post" action="script.php?get=variables">
 <input name="your_inputs" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I gave me this answer with a link in my question :-) Consequently the page is requested by a POST but I can also query the $_GET variables?

Answer (score -2):

Correct Syntax Would Be:

```
if (isset($_GET['StationNr'])) {   
$snr = $_GET['StationNr'];
}else if (isset($_POST['StationNr']))    
$nr = $_POST['StationNr']; 
}
```