# How to do both post and get arguments at the same time in jmeter http request

Tags: jmeter

I have set up several http request samplers in Jmeter that have either get or post parameters and they are all working fine.  However, I am having some trouble setting up http request samplers that post to a URL that has get parameters (i.e. http://www.mydomain.com/myApp.cfm?id1=1&id2=2).  The problem that I am having is that, in the response data tab of my View Results listener, it shows that myApp.cfm is complaining that id1 does not exist.

My configurations of the http request sampler are as follows,
1) Server Name or IP: www.mydomain.com
2) Path: /myApp.cfm?id1=1&id2=2
3) Method: Post
4) Parameters:
  Name: id3
  Value: 3
  Include Equals: True

My question is, how can I use http request sampler to post to a URL that has get parameters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with ColdFusion script and I don't know how you could trick jMeter to get your url params in a POST request (cuz' POST has its params in request body). 
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not) discussion about mixing POST and GET.

Have you tried to save your test using [BadBoy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) or [JMeter Proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) to see what your application actually sends? To see what happens under the hood you can also use `FireBug` if you're using FireFox or `Ctrl+Shift+i` if you're on Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  After using Firebug, as you have suggested, I found the problem was caused by some hidden form field that I have not defined in my test plan.  After defining the hidden form field, the whole thing works as expected.