# struts2 s:form element trims the s:url parameter in the action attribute

Tags: jsp, parameters, struts2

I am using `<s:url>` to create a URL like `removeAction.action?id=10` which should be used by the action attribute in the `<s:form>` element.

The issue here is when the `<s:form>` converts to `<form>` element I can only see the action attribute value as `action="/project/removeAction.action"`. The id parameter is getting trimmed. The result I wanted is `action="/project/removeAction.action?id=10"`

```
<s:url var="actionUrl" action="removeAction" includeContext="false">
  <s:param name="id" value="%{id}" /> 
</s:url>

<s:form action="%{actionUrl}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <div>
  <s:file name="imgUpload"/>
  <s:submit> upload </submit>
 </div>
</s:form>
```

Recently I upgrade the struts2 core version to 2.3.12 and I am getting this issue. This issue starts after version 2.3.4.1

And I don't want to use a `hidden` attribute to pass the parameter as this parameter get lost when the file size is big to upload.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe this is your real problem: `And I don't want to use a hidden attribute to pass the parameter as this parameter get lost when the file size is big to upload.`?

Answer (score 0):

What does it means that the hidden parameter will be lost on file upload with a file too big ? It will be re-read and populated automatically...

- don't call **`RemoveAction`** an action that is actually **UPLOADING** a file. 
  Call it `UploadAction`, for the sake of the logic :|
- [it is not a good idea to use Query Parameters in POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612035/1654265), they should be used only in GET requests, possibly in the REST way...
- To prevent the `max multipart size exceeded` error, put this in `Struts.xml`:

  ```
  <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="52428800" />
  ```
- To tune up the max size (default is 2Mb) for a single file in the `fileUpload Interceptor`, put this in `Struts.xml`, in your `Stack definition`:

  ```
  <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
      <param name="maximumSize">10485760</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  ```

  (with this example, you can upload up to 5 files of 10 MB each one in a row)
- At last, for all the `HTML5` compliant browsers (almost everyone except older IE and some mobile), you can prevent the upload BEFORE IT IS SENT, by checking its size in the `onchange` event like this:

  ```
  <s:file name="imgUpload"/ 
          onchange="javascript:checkFileSize(this);" />

  <script>
      const maxFileSize = 10485760; // 10MB

      function checkFileSize(fileElement){
          if (fileElement.files[0].size > maxFileSize) {
              var mb = (((fileElement.files[0].size) / 1024)/1024).toFixed(2);
              alert("Max file size exceeded: " + mb + " MegaBytes");
              fileElement.value = '';
          }
      }
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use a wildcard mapping

```
<action name="removeAction\\*" class="..">

</action>
```

And pass the id as part of the url it self.e.g: removeAction/101

Refer http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

Answer (score -1):

That issue happens because org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer.renderUrl() method does not find the action configuration for your action "removeAction" because your URL (#actionUrl) already contains the ".action" suffix.

From [struts2 s:form documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/form.html) on the action parameter:

> Set action name to submit to, without .action suffix

The solution is quite simple: do not use `<s:url>` but rather:

```
<s:form action="removeAction?id=%{id}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div>
  <s:file name="imgUpload"/>
  <s:submit> upload </s:submit>
 </div>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Indeed, but looking at renderFormUrl() in ServletUrlRenderer, used by org.apache.struts2.components.Form class, I can see they handle an action name with parameters.  I don't see why %{actionUrl} does not cause the "No action found" error, and why my code works for me and not for you.