# Struts 2 add exception mapping for certain actions

Tags: java, exception, struts2, struts-config

Consider a project with lots of annotated actions.

```
public class TransferMoney(){

    @Action("transfer-money-show-form")
    public String showForm();

    @Action("transfer-money-confirm")
    public String confirmForm();

    @Action("transfer-money-result")
    public String result();
}
```

I want to add exception-mapping to `confirmForm` so I can do it as:

```
@Action(value = "transfer-money-confirm", 
        exceptionMappings = 
                 {@ExceptionMapping(
                       exception = "java.lang.Exception", 
                        result = "exception")
                  }
        )
```

However is it a better way ?! As I said I have lots of actions and I don't want to add `exceptionMapping` for each of them one by one. The action name which I want to add mapping to them all ends with `confirm` but it seems not useful because the Exception Mapping does not accept regex.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16214532/573032).

Comment: Global exception mapping in struts.xml.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27622750/1654265) and @AleskandrM's answer might interest you

Comment: @AleksandrM can i define a pattern for actions in global exception? For example if java.lang.Exception trues and the action name contains 'confirm'  then redirect to a global page

Comment: I think there's no copy/paste solutions yet, dismissed.

Comment: Not with pattern, no. But global exception mappings are per S2 package, so put you all *confirm* actions into separate package and enjoy.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks please send it as answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<global-exception-mappings>` in struts.xml. Global exception mappings are per S2 package, so you can define different mappings for actions by putting them into separate packages.

```
<package name="default">
    ...
    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception"/>
    </global-exception-mappings>
    ...
</package>
```