# Uploading files, saving to database and can be downloaded (struts 2)

Tags: sql, jsp, file-upload, struts2, download

Anybody knows how to upload a file and save it into a database. And it can be viewed in a .jsp page. When the user clicks on it, the user can download it and/or if it is a .doc file (like MS Word .doc, .docx files) it can be viewed online like how facebook implements it.

I am a very very new to uploading files. Please be patient with me. What only I knew is this:

```
<form>
  <input type="file"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

And also, how to limit the file size, and limit only a group of file type like upload only .txt,.doc,.pdf etc files.

Answer (score 1):

From the [File Upload Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/file-upload-interceptor.html) documentation:

> ## Parameters
>
> - **`maximumSize`** (optional) - the maximum size (in bytes) that the interceptor will allow a file reference to be set on the action. Note, this is not related to the various properties found in struts.properties. Default to approximately 2MB.
> - **`allowedTypes`** (optional) - a comma separated list of content types (ie: text/html) that the interceptor will allow a file reference to be set on the action. If none is specified allow all types to be uploaded.
> - **`allowedExtensions`** (optional) - a comma separated list of file extensions (ie: .html) that the interceptor will allow a file reference to be set on the action. If none is specified allow all extensions to be uploaded.

For example, to block all files except `png`, `gif` and `jpeg` under `10 MegaBytes`:

```
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
  <param name="maximumSize">
      10485760
  </param>
  <param name="allowedTypes">
     image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg
  </param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Read more on [File size limit and overall Multipart request size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932363/upload-video-in-struts-2/16936095#16936095).

Be sure to check out the [official Struts2 File Upload page](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/file-upload.html) too for a complete overview of the subject.