# Struts2 Action is not called when more than 4 option given for file uploading

Tags: struts2

```
HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action com.strutsProject.action.AchievementsAction and result input uploading
```

> Struts2 Action is not call when more than 4 option given for file uploading

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="email" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style=" text-align: left;">Upload Photo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="file"class="form-control" data-buttonName="btn-primary"  name="fileUpload7" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style=" text-align: left;">Upload Photo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="file"class="form-control" data-buttonName="btn-primary"  name="fileUpload7" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style=" text-align: left;">Upload Photo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="file" class="form-control" data-buttonName="btn-primary"  name="fileUpload7" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style=" text-align: left;">Upload Photo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="file"class="form-control" data-buttonName="btn-primary"  name="fileUpload7" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style=" text-align: left;">Upload Photo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="file"class="form-control" data-buttonName="btn-primary" name="fileUpload7" >
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Define `input` result and display errors in JSP.

Comment: After adding this -- <result name="input" type="redirect">announcementrPage</result>   , it does not show any error

Comment: Of course not, because you are redirecting.

Comment: After adding this -- <result name="input" type="tiles">announcementrPage</result> , it does not show any error –

Comment: What tag are you using to display error?

Comment: Your avatar is quite scary

Comment: I found the solution, I forget to include for maxmium file size:-<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="104857600" />

Comment: @NaveenMaurya: Add your solution as a answer and accept it to help future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution ,i forget to include below part in struts.xml file if you have used below code do not include  this(`<param name="maximumSize">9097152</param>` ) because this will override the below code

```xml
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="104857600" />
```

Comment: There is no "overriding" here. Read more on the two limits mentioned in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16936095/1654265