# Flask example with POST

Tags: python, rest, flask, lxml

Suppose the following route which accesses an xml file to replace the text of a specific tag with a given xpath (?key=):

```
@app.route('/resource', methods = ['POST'])
def update_text():
    # CODE
```

Then, I would use cURL like this:

```
curl -X POST http://ip:5000/resource?key=listOfUsers/user1 -d "John"
```

The xpath expreesion `listOfUsers/user1` should access the tag `<user1>` to change its current text to "John".

I have no idea on how to achieve this because I'm just starting to learn Flask and REST and I can't find any good example for this specific case. Also, I'd like to use lxml to manipulate the xml file since I already know it.

Could somebody help and provide an example to guide me?

Answer (score 149):

**Before actually answering your question:**

Parameters in a URL (e.g. `key=listOfUsers/user1`) are `GET` parameters and you shouldn't be using them for `POST` requests. A quick explanation of the difference between GET and POST can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get/3477374#3477374).

In your case, to make use of REST principles, you should probably have:

```
http://ip:5000/users
http://ip:5000/users/<user_id>
```

Then, on each URL, you can define the behaviour of different HTTP methods (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`). For example, on `/users/<user_id>`, you want the following:

```
GET /users/<user_id> - return the information for <user_id>
POST /users/<user_id> - modify/update the information for <user_id> by providing the data
PUT - I will omit this for now as it is similar enough to `POST` at this level of depth
DELETE /users/<user_id> - delete user with ID <user_id>
```

So, in your example, you want do a `POST` to `/users/user_1` with the POST data being `"John"`. Then the XPath expression or whatever other way you want to access your data should be hidden from the user and not tightly couple to the URL. This way, if you decide to change the way you store and access data, instead of all your URL's changing, you will simply have to change the code on the server-side.

**Now, the answer to your question**:
Below is a basic semi-pseudocode of how you can achieve what I mentioned above:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/users/<user_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def user(user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        """return the information for <user_id>"""
        .
        .
        .
    if request.method == 'POST':
        """modify/update the information for <user_id>"""
        # you can use <user_id>, which is a str but could
        # changed to be int or whatever you want, along
        # with your lxml knowledge to make the required
        # changes
        data = request.form # a multidict containing POST data
        .
        .
        .
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        """delete user with ID <user_id>"""
        .
        .
        .
    else:
        # POST Error 405 Method Not Allowed
        .
        .
        .
```

There are a lot of other things to consider like the `POST` request content-type but I think what I've said so far should be a reasonable starting point. I know I haven't directly answered the exact question you were asking but I hope this helps you. I will make some edits/additions later as well.

Let me know if I have gotten something wrong.

Comment: do you have to do something special for the POST to get routed back correctly? I have /competitions/<int: id> set up but when the POST occurs, it posts to /competitions instead so my post handling logic is never reached.

Comment: Agree with the body of your answer, but it is perfectly valid to use [query parameters in POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not#answer-10426554).

Answer (score 25):

Here is the example in which you can easily find the way to use Post,GET method and use the same way to add other curd operations as well..

```
#libraries to include

import os
from flask import request, jsonify
from app import app, mongo
import logger
ROOT_PATH = os.environ.get('ROOT_PATH')<br>
@app.route('/get/questions/', methods=['GET', 'POST','DELETE', 'PATCH'])
    def question():
    # request.args is to get urls arguments 


    if request.method == 'GET':
        start = request.args.get('start', default=0, type=int)
        limit_url = request.args.get('limit', default=20, type=int)
        questions = mongo.db.questions.find().limit(limit_url).skip(start);
        data = [doc for doc in questions]
        return jsonify(isError= False,
                    message= "Success",
                    statusCode= 200,
                    data= data), 200

# request.form to get form parameter

    if request.method == 'POST':
        average_time = request.form.get('average_time')
        choices = request.form.get('choices')
        created_by = request.form.get('created_by')
        difficulty_level = request.form.get('difficulty_level')
        question = request.form.get('question')
        topics = request.form.get('topics')

    ##Do something like insert in DB or Render somewhere etc. it's up to you....... :)
```