# Python flask server issue

Tags: python, flask, server

Could you please help me with Python-Flask server misunderstanding. I have some project with flask, it perfectly works on local server 127.0.0.1, but when I moved it to the Web Server (blue host), some of my script give me these errors:

Here I have jQuery, Ajax response to show a table without reloading page:

```
<button class="myButton" id = "Lbutton">Load</button>

<script>

$("#Lbutton").click(function(){

  $.ajax({
          url: "/table,
          type: "get",
          data: {jsdata: $( "#select option:selected" ).text()},
          success: function(response) {
            $("#place_for_suggestions").html(response);

          },
          error: function(xhr) {
            // handle error
          }
        });

});

</script>
```

**url: "/table,** is the link for Flask function:

```
@FlaskApp2.route('/table')
def table():

    modid = request.args.get('jsdata')
    return render_template('table.html')
```

But finally the Server gave me error:

> File does not exist: /home1/user/public_html/**table**

Why direct link for action, server understand like a link for a file?

So, every action to Python-Flask

```
<form action="/sendemail" method="post">
```

the Server understand like a link and give an error message !

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Solved, I need to put the full path in action and route() decorator @app.route "/.../templates/table.html"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add the `POST` method to your `route` definition.

```
@FlaskApp2.route('/table')
```

becomes:

```
@FlaskApp2.route('/table', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Check out the documentation here: 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#http-methods

Which has an example of an endpoint that accepts both GET and POST HTTP methods.

Also check out a related question: [Flask example with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947905/flask-example-with-post)

Comment: Tried, doesn't help! Why its work on local server 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Maybe I need to write a full path in url: "templates/table",