# Flask web-app input for selenium browser automation

Tags: python, selenium, flask, web, automation

I have a simple Flask web app for logging into my electric company
dashboard. I have a page called `essentials`. The essentials page has a
form set up, for user input.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By import time

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/') 
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/essentials') 
def essentials():
    return render_template('essentials.html')

@app.route('/form', methods=['POST']) 
def form():
    username = request.form.get("user_name")
    password = request.form.get("password") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then i have some selenium code for filling user authentication form automatically:

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.set_window_size(1100, 800)

driver.get('https://www.firstenergycorp.com/content/customer/jersey_central_power_light.html')
    
username = 
password = 
    
    
driver.find_element_by_id('loginUsername').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('loginPwd').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id('loginPwd').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(7)
```

**Question**: How do i pass the flask form web user inputs **(username, password)**, into the selenium variables in this case `username` and `password` that it will then use for the automation part?

Comment: Run the selenium code inside `def form`. The function should run when the `METHOD` is `POST`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are submitting a form with method `POST`, then you can try this

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def form():
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get("user_name")
        password = request.form.get("password") 
        
        driver = webdriver.Safari()
        driver.set_window_size(1100, 800)

        driver.get('https://www.firstenergycorp.com/content/customer/jersey_central_power_light.html')

        driver.find_element_by_id('loginUsername').send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id('loginPwd').send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_id('loginPwd').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(7)
    
    else:
        # what do you want to display if method is not "post"
```

#### References:

1. [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/)
2. [Handling GET and POST in same Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018603/handling-get-and-post-in-same-flask-view)
3. [Flask example with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947905/flask-example-with-post)

Comment: If this solved your issue, please upvote and accept the answer. This will help other facing  the similar issue

Comment: The simplest things, make all the difference. Thanks a bunch, it worked.

Comment: By the way,i have the selenium automation within a function. How would i use the variables 'username' and 'password' generated by post request, use them as variables within the new function called SeleniumAutomation.py?

Comment: Hi. I think what you would need is to do is to pass the `username` and `password` as arguments to the function. You can call the function inside the `POST request`.