# add default query parameter to angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have an angular resource configured as follows:

```
var resource = $resource('/api', {}, {
        get: {
           ....
        },
        ...,
        submit: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                test: true
            }
        }
```

Now, when I call **submit** I would like the url to look like

```
/api?test=true
```

However, what I have not doesn't do that, the parameter is ignored. So the question is how do I add this default query param for my submit action ?

Comment: Why `POST` plus query parameters? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not

Answer (score 1):

[`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) supports path params as in the example:

```
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
  {userId:123, cardId:'@id'},
  {charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
});
```

Use this pattern instead of query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var resource = $resource('/api?test=:test', {}, {
        get: {
           ....
        },
        ...,
        submit: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                test: true
            }
        }
```