# Servlet get GET and POST's parameters at the doPost method

Tags: java, servlets

My problem is when I'm trying to access a `POST` Variable with `request.getParameter("name")`, it works perfectly. But in some conditions, when a `POST` request arrives at my application, I also need to get `GET` Parameter from the Query String.

As far as I can see, with `getParameter`, you can only access current request's parameters, but, as in my condition, as I said, I also need to fetch `GET` Parameters inside `doPost` method.

Is there a way to fetch `GET` Parameters without parsing the Query String?

Comment: Mixing GET with POST is just a really bad idea

Comment: @ErolKESKİN read my answer plz and tell me if it makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getParameter()` method can return (if possible) both GET and POST parameters as it works transparently between `GET` and `POST`. You don't need to do any explicit work to get the GET parameters. you can use `getParameter` for both query parameters and POST parameters.

But should you do it? - It's considered a poor design practice especially if there is sensitive information to be sent.

Take a look at this answer:

- [HTTP POST with URL query parameters -- good idea or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not)

Comment: No, you don't need to do any explicit work to get the GET parameters. you can use `getParameter` for both query parameters and POST parameters.

Answer (score 3):

If you have parameters with the same name in the query string and in the posted form data, use `getParameterValues()`.

Example:-

```
String fromQuery = request.getParameterValues("name")[0];
String fromForm = request.getParameterValues("name")[1];
```

Comment: you can add that getParameter("name") will return the value at the first index (the querystring value)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a confusion here. You can retrieve all the request parameters (in both GET or POST or others) using the same `getParameter(..)` depending upon the type of request. If it's a GET request, you can retrieve all the GET parameters.

If it's a POST request, you can retrieve all the POST parameters. You get parameters using `getParameter(...)`. And you make one request at a time. If you make a POST request in html or JSP file, you use doPost method receive all the parameters. At this point, there is nothing in GET request. Then after that, you make a GET request, you retrieve all the parameters in doGet method. At this moment, there is nothing in POST. Remember, HTTP requests are stateless.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Rei answer check out this code :

your form

```
<form action="?nom=nom1">
<input type="hidden" name="nom" value="nm2"/>
```

your doPost

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("nom"));
        
String s = "";
for(String ss : request.getParameterValues("nom")) {
    s += "|" + ss;
}
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(request.getParameterMap().get("nom"));
```

what will be printed

```
nom1
|nom1|nm2
[Ljava.lang.String;@c7068db
```

ps : thanks to Julien for the code and testing