# Request.data or Request.query_params to access params in POST?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a simple API and I'm trying to test POST request. Post request should create a new record based on only one param: title.

I'm using manage.py test for testing and I've set up the client:

```
client = rest_framework.test.APIClient()
```

Problem: it works fine when I'm giving the URL manually ("snatch" is a title of a movie).

```
response = client.post('/movies/?title=snatch', format='json')
```

In this case I can access the title in my view request.query_params.get('title') and request.data.get('title').

But when I'm trying to pass the title in data argument:

```
response = client.post('/movies/', data={'title':'snatch'}, format='json')
```

This should access '/movies/?title=snatch', but instead accesses only '/movies/'.
I can access the title through request.data.get('title'), but not through request.query_params.get('title').

How should I access the params sent in POST request? Is accessing through request.data a correct way?
Can someone give me a better explanation of the differences and use cases?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not)

Comment: Thanks, included the link in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**request.data** hold the data sent in request body, i.e with the **data** parameter here:

```
response = client.post('/movies/', data={'title':'snatch'}, format='json')
```

**request.query_params** hold the data sent in query string parameters, i.e title here:

```
response = client.post('/movies/?title=snatch', format='json')
```

To exepmlyfy, if you send such a request:

```
response = client.post('/movies/?director=guyritchie', data={'title':'snatch'}, format='json')
```

you can get **director** parameter through **request.query_params**, and **title** parameter through **request.data**

More on difference between data and query_params:
[HTTP POST with URL query parameters -- good idea or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I edited the answer the include a link from Waket Zheng, as it also helped me to understand the issue.